# How do you get the logical xor of two variables in Python?

Tags: python, logical-operators

How do you get the [logical xor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) of two variables in Python?

For example, I have two variables that I expect to be strings. I want to test that only one of them contains a True value (is not None or an empty string):

```py
str1 = raw_input("Enter string one:")
str2 = raw_input("Enter string two:")
if logical_xor(str1, str2):
    print "ok"
else:
    print "bad"
```

The `^` operator is bitwise, and not defined on all objects:

```
>>> 1 ^ 1
0
>>> 2 ^ 1
3
>>> "abc" ^ ""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'str' and 'str'
```

Comment: How do you define "xor" for a couple of strings? What do you feel "abc" ^ "" should return that it doesn't?

Comment: It should return True, rather than raise an exception, since only one of the strings is True as defined by normal Python's bool type.

Comment: I'm amazed that Python doesn't have an infix operator called "xor", which would be the most intuitive, Pythonic implementation. Using "^" is consistent with other languages, but not as blatantly readable as most of Python is.

Comment: @MehrdadAfshari The obvious answer to your question is that `a xor a` is defined as `(a and not b) or (not a and b)`, and so `a xor b`, when `a` and `b` are character strings, or any other types, should yield whatever `(a and not b) or (not a and b)` yields.

Comment: The issue is that documentation is poor.  ^ is "bitwise exclusive or", which literally interpreted means bit by bit, not bool by bool. so x'FFFF00' ^ x'FFFF00'  should be x'000000'.  Or is this only meant to occur on a char by char basis ? cast as numbers ?  We need to iterate the shorter string characters to match the length of the longer string. All this should be built in.

Comment: @mckenzm If that helps your point, `int("0xFFFF00", 16) ^ int("0xFFFF00", 16) == int(0)` so yes you have to cast as number and call `hex` on the result, then pad the result with enough 0 on the left to reach the longest length.

Answer (score 1689, accepted):

If you're already normalizing the inputs to booleans, then != is xor.

```
bool(a) != bool(b)
```

Comment: Although this is clever and short, I'm not convinced it's clean. When someone reads this construct in the code, is it immediately obvious to them that this is an xor operation? I felt obliged to add a comment - a sign for me that I'm writing unclear code and try to apologise with a comment.

Comment: Perhaps "is it clear that it's an XOR?" is the wrong question.  We were just trying to see whether the answer to two questions are the same, and thinking we'd use XOR to implement that.  For example, if we want to ensure that we are not comparing apples to oranges, is "if xor( isApple(x), isApple(y) )" really clearer than "if isApple(x) != isApple(y)" ?  Not to me!

Comment: There is problem with using "!=" as xor. You would probably expect
bool(a) != bool(b) != bool(c) to be the same as bool(a) ^ bool(b) ^ bool(c). So do casts to bool, but I would recommend ^. To know what's going up in the first example look up "operator chaining".

Comment: @elmo: +1 for pointing out the difference, and +1 for teaching me what operator chaining is! I am in the camp that says that != is not as readable as ^.

Comment: Just a tip for the ingenuous like me: be careful with operator precedence!
I wanted to check if two variables  were both null or both non-null and ended up writing `(a is None != b is None)`.  Well, that's wrong!

Comment: should it be `bool(a) is not bool(b)` instead?

Comment: Is this the real answer? I try this code on my machine, `print bool("Hellow World") == bool("H")`, it returns `True`

Comment: @Jason You're using `==` instead of `!=`.   You can verify by brute force if necessary: `for b1, b2 in ((True, False), (True, True), (False, False): assert (b1 != b2) == (b1 ^ b1)`.  This is verification by truth table (noting the commutativity of the operator). I'll leave it as an exercise to verify using inference rules ;)

Comment: Not only this make the code hard to understand, as pointed out by @elmo this is NOT equivalent to xor operation and can lead to hard to spot bugs in the code. [operator.xor](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.xor) would be a better alternative.

Comment: Downvoting because this answer is WRONG (since as pointed out by @elmo `!=` is not XOR in python)

Comment: @Arel: For `bool`, for a single comparison, `!=` is exactly the same as xor. It's only for the chained case where the behavior differs. Not worth a downvote.

Comment: @ShadowRanger xor (`^`) is xor. Not-equals (`!=`) is not xor in Python because of a subtle reason that could have been clarified in the answer but wasn't. You're right that it works in the two-variable case like the question asks, but the assertion that `!=` is xor is inaccurate and unnecessary. I tried to edit this question (twice) to add a clarification, but reviewers rejected my changes. Hence, downvote.

Comment: Why blame the respondent for poor reviewers?

Comment: @RNA No, don't compare booleans with `is`. [This answer explains why in the second section](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9494887/4518341). [PEP 8 also mentions it, but doesn't explain](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations).

Comment: @wjandrea That post seems incomplete for `bool(x) is True`. We can be sure the value returned by bool will be either True or False.

Comment: @Josiah Yes, but we can't be sure that `True is True` because that's an implementation detail.

Comment: @wjandrea `True is True` is [guaranteed by the Python language reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy).  [Thanks Pedro, for asking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24842852/is-there-only-one-true-and-one-false-object-in-python)

Comment: @Josiah Oh, huh, the answer I linked must be wrong, or out of date. Still, equality comparison is more intuitive than identity comparison, even though they do the same thing for two bools.

Comment: For a single comparison, this construction has the advantage of interpreting `None` as `False` whereas `^` on `None` throws a `TypeError`

Answer (score 699):

You can always use the definition of xor to compute it from other logical operations:

```
(a and not b) or (not a and b)
```

But this is a little too verbose for me, and isn't particularly clear at first glance. Another way to do it is:

```
bool(a) ^ bool(b)
```

The xor operator on two booleans is logical xor (unlike on ints, where it's bitwise). Which makes sense, since [`bool` is just a subclass of `int`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=bool#bool), but is implemented to only have the values `0` and `1`. And logical xor is equivalent to bitwise xor when the domain is restricted to `0` and `1`.

So the `logical_xor` function would be implemented like:

```
def logical_xor(str1, str2):
    return bool(str1) ^ bool(str2)
```

Credit to [Nick Coghlan on the Python-3000 mailing list](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2007-December/011560.html).

Comment: great post, but of all ways to name your parameters, why 'str1' and 'str2'?

Comment: @Zach Hirsch Could you use (not a and b) instead of (b and not a) for readability or would the definition be inconsistent with xor.

Comment: You should put the nots first like this `(not b and a) or (not a and b)` so that it returns the string if there was one, which seems like the pythonic way for the function to operate.

Comment: I was thinking about saying something about both inputs being invoked before the function is called (which is often a downside of implementing your own boolean functions), but then I remembered that xor can't short circuit anyway. You might want to make note of that.

Answer (score 244):

*Bitwise* exclusive-or is already built-in to Python, in the [`operator`](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.xor) module (which is identical to the `^` operator):

```py
from operator import xor
xor(bool(a), bool(b))  # Note: converting to bools is essential
```

###### IMPORTANT NOTE

*"Be careful, this is also bitwise: xor(1, 2) returns 3. From the docstring: xor(a, b) -- Same as a ^ b. Remember that anything imported from operator is just a functional form of an existing builtin infix operator.  – askewchan Sep 15, 2013 at 16:59 "*

Comment: This is what I needed.  When reverse engineering malware lots of times strings are mangled until an XOR operation.  Using this chr(xor(ord("n"), 0x1A)) = 't'

Comment: Be careful, this is also bitwise: `xor(1, 2)` returns `3`.  From the docstring:  `xor(a, b) -- Same as a ^ b.`  Remember that anything imported from `operator` is just a functional form of an existing builtin infix operator.

Comment: @askewchan: The `bool` type overloads `__xor__` to return booleans. It'll work just fine, but its overkill when `bool(a) ^ bool(b)` does exactly the same thing.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The `^` operator calls `__xor__` internally.

Comment: @Quantum7: yes, I'm not sure why you are telling me this though. I just said that the `bool` type implements the `__xor__` method *specifically because `^` calls it*. The point being that `bool(a) ^ bool(b)` works fine, there is no need to use the `operator.xor()` function here.

Comment: ^ commonly means "to the power of". So it might look kind of like "True to the power of False = True". Bear in mind that True != 1 even if that's how it works in Python and C++.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, sometimes using a method like `operator.xor` is useful because it's an object that can be passed around. Obviously you could write your own method, but why do that when there's already a built-in?

Comment: @EdwardSpencer: absolutely, when you need to parametrize the expression, the `operator` module is fantastic. But the way this answer was worded when it was first posted and before Arel adding in the `^` operator, the answer seemed to imply that `operator.xor()` was the only way to do this.

Comment: This is more readable than `^`.

Answer (score 57):

As [Zach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432842/how-do-you-get-the-logical-xor-of-two-variables-in-python#432844) explained, you can use:

```
xor = bool(a) ^ bool(b)
```

Personally, I favor a slightly different dialect:

```
xor = bool(a) + bool(b) == 1
```

This dialect is inspired from a logical diagramming language I learned in school where "OR" was denoted by a box containing `≥1` (greater than or equal to 1) and "XOR" was denoted by a box containing `=1`.

This has the advantage of correctly implementing exclusive or on multiple operands.

- "1 = a ^ b ^ c..." means the number of true operands is odd. This operator is "parity".
- "1 = a + b + c..." means exactly one operand is true. This is "exclusive or", meaning "one to the exclusion of the others".

Comment: So, True + True + False + True == 3, and 3 != 1, but True XOR True XOR False XOR True == True. Can you elaborate on "correctly implementing XOR on multiple operands"?

Comment: @ΤΖΩΤΖΙΟΥ: Wrap it in a `bool()`

Comment: @tzot Your example fails, because according to ddaa's solution, you apply the addition on only two variables at a time. So the right way to write it all out would have to be `(((((True + True)==1)+False)==1)+True)==1`. The answer given here totally generalizes to multiple operands.

Comment: Also, there's a difference between a three-way XOR vs. order-of-operations-grouped set of two XORs. So 3-WAY-XOR(A,B,C) is *not* the same thing as XOR(XOR(A,B),C). And ddaa's example is the former, while yours assumes the latter.

Comment: @EMS: thanks. Your objections clarified (to me) what ddaa meant.

Comment: @Mr.F Your explanation doesn't really excuse this answer. In Python, if you just do `True + True + False + True`, you *do* get `3`, and `True + True + False + True == 3` gives back `True` while `True + True + False + True == 1` gives back `False`. In other words, the answer here doesn't generalize correctly; for it to do so, you need to do additional work. Meanwhile a simple `True ^ True ^ False ^ True` works as expected.

Comment: @jpmc26 I do not understand your comment. The addition approach is meant to generalize the operation in which you want to check that *exactly one* operand is `True`, a multi-arity XOR. This is a different operation than, for example, `A XOR B XOR ... XOR Z`. In other words, if you plan to use the addition-based version, then upon submitted the operands in `True + True + False + True` you should expect the result to be `False` since more than one of those is `True`, which works if the condition checks for `== 1`.

Comment: So when you write `True + True + False + True == 1` gives back `False` that's correct and desired if you're using the addition approach. Maybe I'm misunderstanding your point, but I don't see what's wrong. Whether a person wants one or the other operation is up to them, and for multi-arity XOR, it's just a matter of semantics as to which of these "is XOR".

Comment: (bool(a) + bool(b) + bool(c)) % 2 == 1 would work but it's not worth `^`-ing.

Comment: Does the language guarantee that
bool(a)^bool(b)
will be a bool (rather than just an int)?  If so, where is the guarantee documented?  Thanks.

Comment: @ddaa I don't see why.  It is a crucial consideration for your first proposed answer.

Comment: @ddaa Let's just say it is the assumption embodied in the current behavior of CPython.  I'm just asking if you know what type your first proposed answer will return in any valid Python implementation.  It is a simple question, even if you have some personal aversion to `is`.

Comment: You are assuming there is such a thing as a "valid Python implementation". There is no such thing as far as I know. Therefore your question is invalid.

Comment: Indeed there is. That's why you can run the same python program on multiple differently implemented interpreters

Comment: Addition to get XOR obtuse and unclear, violating PEP 20 "Explicit is better than implicit. Simple is better than complex.", downvoting

Comment: You can even do this more elegantly with more than 2 operands using sum(), map() and bool(), by doing something like `sum(map(bool, operand_list)) == 1`.

Answer (score 35):

- Python logical `or`: `A or B`: returns `A` if `bool(A)` is `True`, otherwise returns `B`
- Python logical `and`: `A and B`: returns `A` if `bool(A)` is `False`, otherwise returns `B`

To keep most of that way of thinking, my logical xor definintion would be:

```
def logical_xor(a, b):
    if bool(a) == bool(b):
        return False
    else:
        return a or b
```

That way it can return `a`, `b`, or `False`:

```
>>> logical_xor('this', 'that')
False
>>> logical_xor('', '')
False
>>> logical_xor('this', '')
'this'
>>> logical_xor('', 'that')
'that'
```

Comment: This seems bad, or at least weird, to me. None of the other built-in logical operators return one of three possible values.

Comment: @Zach Hirsch: That's why I said "to keep *most* of that way of thinking" - since there's no good result when both are true or false

Comment: Logical operation must return logical value, so second "return a or b" looks strange, so second return must return True.

Comment: @Denis Barmenkov: Well, note that python logical operators `and` and `or` won't return logical value. `'foo' and 'bar'` returns `'bar'` ...

Comment: At first sight, the 2 previous answers seem like the best, but on second thought, this one is actually the only truly correct one, i.e. it's the only one that provides an example of a `xor` implementation that is consistent with the built-in `and` and `or`. However, of course, in practical situations, `bool(a) ^ bool(b)` or even `a ^ b` (if `a` and `b` are known to be `bool`) are more concise of course.

Answer (score 34):

I've tested several approaches (including using the `truth()` function as ShadowRanger suggested).

```
%timeit  (not a) ^  (not b)   # 47 ns
%timeit  (not a) != (not b)   # 44.7 ns
%timeit truth(a) != truth(b)  # 116 ns
%timeit  bool(a) != bool(b)   # 190 ns
```

Comment: That's 100 ns of my life I won't get back ;-)

Comment: For an in-between timing, you can do `from operator import truth` at the top of the module, and test `truth(a) != truth(b)`. `bool` being a constructor has a lot of unavoidable overhead at the C level (it must accept arguments as the equivalent of `*args, **kwargs` and parse the `tuple` and `dict` to extract them), where `truth` (being a function) can use an optimized path that doesn't require either a `tuple` or a `dict`, and runs in about half the time of `bool` based solutions (but still longer than `not` based solutions).

Comment: Which version of which Python implementation does this refer to?

Comment: @LutzPrechelt unfortunately I don't remember; Probably 3.5

Comment: Should note your timings are python 3.  Python 2.7 timings match for `not` and `bool`, but `truth (a) != truth (b)` is about 50ns instead of 100+.  So on par with `not` methods.

Comment: `(not a) is not (not b)` is faster than `(not a) != (not b)`.

Answer (score 29):

Python has a bitwise exclusive-OR operator, it's `^`:

```
>>> True ^ False
True
>>> True ^ True
False
>>> False ^ True
True
>>> False ^ False
False
```

You can use it by converting the inputs to booleans before applying xor (`^`):

```
bool(a) ^ bool(b)
```

(Edited - thanks Arel)

Comment: Your answer should make clear that `^` is a *bitwise* xor (not logical xor like the question asked). `bool(2) ^ bool(3)` gives a different answer than `bool(2 ^ 3)`.

Comment: @Arel But that's not the case.  `a ^ b` is polymorph.  If `a` and `b` are `bool` instances, the result will be `bool` as well.  This behavior can hardly be called a "bitwise" xor.

Comment: @Alfe the important point is that _values must be cast to booleans first._ The Python documentation defines `^` as bitwise, even though it's an interesting point that types are preserved for `bool` and `int` types. Note: `True ^ 2` is `3`, demonstrating how it is indeed bitwise.

Comment: @Arel Yes, the `bool ^ int` case is kind of casting everything to `int` first.  Still, Python has built-in the `^` operator for many bits in `int` and for the one bit represented in a `bool`, so both are _bitwise_, but the _bitwise_ xor for a single bit just _is_ the _logical_ xor for booleans.

Comment: I always hate using this operator, although I understand it is `xor`, coming from an engineering background, to me this instinctively feels like a mathematical power, ie `2^3 = pow(2,3)` which means I always explicitly comment to prevent confusion.

Answer (score 17):

Simple, easy to understand:

```
sum(bool(a), bool(b)) == 1
```

If an exclusive choice is what you're after, i.e. to select `1` choice out of `n`, it can be expanded to multiple arguments:

```
sum(bool(x) for x in y) == 1
```

Comment: `sum(map(bool, y)) % 2 == 1`

Comment: I see little reason to use `sum` if you just have 2 variables, `bool(a) + bool(b) == 1` does the same thing.

Comment: @Boris Potayto potarto

Comment: @cz I'm glad that you agree that one is clearly wrong :)

Answer (score 13):

To get the logical xor of two or more variables in Python:

1. Convert inputs to booleans
2. Use the bitwise xor operator (`^` or `operator.xor`)

For example,

```py
bool(a) ^ bool(b)
```

When you convert the inputs to booleans, *bitwise* xor becomes *logical* xor.

**Note that the accepted answer is wrong:** `!=` is not the same as xor in Python because of the subtlety of *operator chaining*.

For instance, the xor of the three values below is wrong when using `!=`:

```py
True ^  False ^  False  # True, as expected of XOR
True != False != False  # False! Equivalent to `(True != False) and (False != False)`
```

(P.S. I tried editing the accepted answer to include this warning, but my change was rejected.)

Answer (score 13):

Given that A and B are bools.

```
A is not B
```

Answer (score 12):

As I don't see the simple variant of xor using variable arguments and only operation on Truth values True or False, I'll just throw it here for anyone to use.
It's as noted by others, pretty (not to say very) straightforward.

```
def xor(*vars):
    result = False
    for v in vars:
        result = result ^ bool(v)
    return result
```

And usage is straightforward as well:

```
if xor(False, False, True, False):
    print "Hello World!"
```

As this is the generalized n-ary logical XOR, it's truth value will be True whenever the number of True operands is odd (and not only when exactly one is True, this is just one case in which n-ary XOR is True).

Thus if you are in search of a n-ary predicate that is only True when exactly one of it's operands is, you might want to use:

```
def isOne(*vars):
    result = False
    for v in vars:
        if result and v:
            return False
        else:
            result = result or v
    return result
```

Comment: For improving this answer: `(bool(False) is False) == True`.

You can just use `False` on those lines.

Answer (score 10):

Rewarding thread:

Anoder idea... Just you try the (may be) pythonic expression «is not» in order to get behavior of logical «xor»

The truth table would be:

```
>>> True is not True
False
>>> True is not False
True
>>> False is not True
True
>>> False is not False
False
>>>
```

And for your example string:

```
>>> "abc" is not  ""
True
>>> 'abc' is not 'abc' 
False
>>> 'abc' is not '' 
True
>>> '' is not 'abc' 
True
>>> '' is not '' 
False
>>>
```

However; as they indicated above, it depends of the actual behavior you want to pull out about any couple strings, because strings aren't boleans... and even more: if you «Dive Into Python» you will find «The Peculiar Nature of "and" and "or"»
http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/and_or.html

Sorry my writed English, it's not my born language.

Regards.

Comment: I also use to read it as "strictly different". That's because some languages use to implement the operation bit by bit of the binary representation and take the bool of the resulting bitwise operation. I guess your answer is more "type-bulletproofed" because it extends beyond the boolean space.

Comment: I mean the fact that your answer cover the case of comparing None, False, '' as different is the distinctive stuff. For example: bool(False) != bool('') nevertheless False is not ''" agrees more with this semantics of "strictly different"

Answer (score 9):

You use the same XOR operator like in C, which is `^`.

I don't know why, but the most upvoted solution suggests `bool(A) != bool(B)`, while I would say - in conformity with C's `^`'s operator, the most obvious solution is:

```
bool(A) ^ bool(B)
```

which is more readable and immediately understandable for anyone coming from `C` or any `C`-derived language ...

when doing code-golfing, probably

```
not A ^ (not B)
```

will be the winner. with `not` as converter for boolean (one letter less than `bool()`. And for the first expression in some cases one can leave out the parantheses. Well, it depends, in cases where one has to do `not(A) ^ (not(B))`, the `bool()` needs same amount of letters ...

Comment: `not not A` is another way to get the same result as `bool(A)` without a function call.

Answer (score 8):

I know this is late, but I had a thought and it might be worth, just for documentation. Perhaps this would work:`np.abs(x-y)` The idea is that

1. if x=True=1 and y=False=0 then the result would be |1-0|=1=True
2. if x=False=0 and y=False=0 then the result would be |0-0|=0=False
3. if x=True=1 and y=True=1 then the result would be |1-1|=0=False
4. if x=False=0 and y=True=1 then the result would be |0-1|=1=True

Comment: You could even drop the `abs`, python interprets negative numbers as truthy, although this is very obscure imo (what does `if (x > 1) - (y > 3)` mean?

Answer (score 8):

Many folks, including myself, need an `xor` function that behaves like an n-input xor circuit, where n is variable.  (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_gate).  The following simple function implements this.

```
def xor(*args):
   """
   This function accepts an arbitrary number of input arguments, returning True
   if and only if bool() evaluates to True for an odd number of the input arguments.
   """

   return bool(sum(map(bool,args)) % 2)
```

Sample I/O follows:

```
In [1]: xor(False, True)
Out[1]: True

In [2]: xor(True, True)
Out[2]: False

In [3]: xor(True, True, True)
Out[3]: True
```

Comment: I usually prefer generator comprehensions over using `map`, since they are usually faster and (for me personally) generally more explicit, so I'd use `bool(sum(bool(a) for a in args) % 2)`. On the other hand, I think `map` is slightly faster with built-in functions (like `bool`). A good solution anyways +1.

Answer (score 7):

Exclusive Or is defined as follows

```
def xor( a, b ):
    return (a or b) and not (a and b)
```

Comment: that would return True for xor('this', '') and to follow python's way, it should return 'this'.

Comment: @nosklo: Take it up with the BDFL, please, not me.  Since Python returns True, then that *must* be Python's way.

Comment: I mean for consistency with the other python logical operators - Python doesn't return True when I do ('this' or ''), it returns 'this'. But in your function xor('this', '') returns True. It should return 'this' as the "or" python builtin does.

Comment: Python `and` and `or` do short-circuit. Any `xor` implementation can't short-circuit, so there is already a discrepancy; therefore, there is no reason that `xor` should operate like `and`+`or` do.

Answer (score 7):

Some of the implementations suggested here will cause repeated evaluation of the operands  in some cases, which may lead to unintended side effects and therefore must be avoided.

That said, a `xor` implementation that returns either `True` or `False` is fairly simple; one that returns one of the operands, if possible, is much trickier, because no consensus exists as to which operand should be the chosen one, especially when there are more than two operands. For instance, should `xor(None, -1, [], True)` return `None`, `[]` or `False`? I bet each answer appears to some people as the most intuitive one.

For either the True- or the False-result, there are as many as five possible choices: return first operand (if it matches end result in value, else boolean), return first match (if at least one exists, else boolean), return last operand (if ... else ...), return last match (if ... else ...), or always return boolean. Altogether, that's 5 ** 2 = 25 flavors of `xor`.

```
def xor(*operands, falsechoice = -2, truechoice = -2):
  """A single-evaluation, multi-operand, full-choice xor implementation
  falsechoice, truechoice: 0 = always bool, +/-1 = first/last operand, +/-2 = first/last match"""
  if not operands:
    raise TypeError('at least one operand expected')
  choices = [falsechoice, truechoice]
  matches = {}
  result = False
  first = True
  value = choice = None
  # avoid using index or slice since operands may be an infinite iterator
  for operand in operands:
    # evaluate each operand once only so as to avoid unintended side effects
    value = bool(operand)
    # the actual xor operation
    result ^= value
    # choice for the current operand, which may or may not match end result
    choice = choices[value]
    # if choice is last match;
    # or last operand and the current operand, in case it is last, matches result;
    # or first operand and the current operand is indeed first;
    # or first match and there hasn't been a match so far
    if choice < -1 or (choice == -1 and value == result) or (choice == 1 and first) or (choice > 1 and value not in matches):
      # store the current operand
      matches[value] = operand
    # next operand will no longer be first
    first = False
  # if choice for result is last operand, but they mismatch
  if (choices[result] == -1) and (result != value):
    return result
  else:
    # return the stored matching operand, if existing, else result as bool
    return matches.get(result, result)

testcases = [
  (-1, None, True, {None: None}, [], 'a'),
  (None, -1, {None: None}, 'a', []),
  (None, -1, True, {None: None}, 'a', []),
  (-1, None, {None: None}, [], 'a')]
choices = {-2: 'last match', -1: 'last operand', 0: 'always bool', 1: 'first operand', 2: 'first match'}
for c in testcases:
  print(c)
  for f in sorted(choices.keys()):
    for t in sorted(choices.keys()):
      x = xor(*c, falsechoice = f, truechoice = t)
      print('f: %d (%s)\tt: %d (%s)\tx: %s' % (f, choices[f], t, choices[t], x))
  print()
```

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes I find myself working with 1 and 0 instead of boolean True and False values.  In this case xor can be defined as

```
z = (x + y) % 2
```

which has the following truth table:

```
     x
   |0|1|
  -+-+-+
  0|0|1|
y -+-+-+
  1|1|0|
  -+-+-+
```

Answer (score 6):

How about this?

```
(not b and a) or (not a and b)
```

will give `a` if `b` is false
will give `b` if `a` is false
will give `False` otherwise

Or with the Python 2.5+ ternary expression:

```
(False if a else b) if b else a
```

Answer (score 6):

Xor is `^` in Python. It returns :

- A bitwise xor for ints
- Logical xor for bools
- An exclusive union for sets
- User-defined results for classes that implements `__xor__`.
- TypeError for undefined types, such as strings or dictionaries.

If you intend to use them on strings anyway, casting them in `bool` makes your operation unambiguous (you could also mean `set(str1) ^ set(str2)`).

Answer (score 6):

This is how I would code up any truth table. For xor in particular we have:

```
| a | b  | xor   |             |
|---|----|-------|-------------|
| T | T  | F     |             |
| T | F  | T     | a and not b |
| F | T  | T     | not a and b |
| F | F  | F     |             |
```

Just look at the T values in the answer column and string together all true cases with logical or. So, this truth table may be produced in case 2 or 3. Hence,

```
xor = lambda a, b: (a and not b) or (not a and b)
```

Answer (score 4):

It's easy when you know what XOR does:

```
def logical_xor(a, b):
    return (a and not b) or (not a and b)

test_data = [
  [False, False],
  [False, True],
  [True, False],
  [True, True],
]

for a, b in test_data:
    print '%r xor %s = %r' % (a, b, logical_xor(a, b))
```

Answer (score 4):

The meaning of [Exclusive Or (XOR) can be confusing](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/93719/369191) but may have lead you here.

Here is an exclusivity check that functions like the [traditional XOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) for two variables but operates like [One-Hot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot) for multiple variables.

The only benefit I can see above [other implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71231133/2128265) is that it short circuits and is less magical.

```py
    def exclusive(*opts):
        count = 0
        for value in opts:
            if bool(value):  # If truthy
                count += 1
                if count > 1:  # Short-circuit
                    return False
        return count == 1  # Only Return True if one truthy found
```

Here's a table of those differences between XOR and ONE-HOT as an example:

```
a|b|c|d --- xor|one-hot
-----------------------
0|0|0|0 --> 0  |0  
0|0|0|1 --> 1  |1  
0|0|1|0 --> 1  |1  
0|0|1|1 --> 0  |0  
0|1|0|0 --> 1  |1  
0|1|0|1 --> 0  |0  
0|1|1|0 --> 0  |0  
0|1|1|1 --> 1  |0  # noted difference
1|0|0|0 --> 1  |1  
1|0|0|1 --> 0  |0  
1|0|1|0 --> 0  |0  
1|0|1|1 --> 1  |0  # noted difference
1|1|0|0 --> 0  |0  
1|1|0|1 --> 1  |0  # noted difference
1|1|1|0 --> 1  |0  # noted difference
1|1|1|1 --> 0  |0
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an implementation of the map-reduce generalization.  Note that this is equivalent to `functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x != y, map(bool, orands))`.

```
def xor(*orands):
    return bool(sum(bool(x) for x in orands) % 2)
```

Here's a generalization if you're looking for a one-hot detector.  This generalization may fit the English language use of exclusive-or, (e.g. "For a dollar you can buy a juice or coffee or tea"), but it doesn't match the typical order of operations.  E.g.`xor_1hot(1,1,1) == 0 != 1 == xor_1hot(xor_1hot(1,1),1)`.

```
def xor_1hot(*orands):
    return sum(bool(x) for x in orands) == 1
```

You can test either with

```
# test
from itertools import product
n = 3
total_true = 0
for inputs in product((False, True), repeat=n):
    y = xor(*inputs)
    total_true += int(y)
    print(f"{''.join(str(int(b)) for b in inputs)}|{y}")
print('Total True:', total_true)
```

One-Hot Detector Output:

> 000|False
> 001|True
> 010|True
> 011|False
> 100|True
> 101|False
> 110|False
> 111|False
> Total True: 3

Map-Reduce Output:

> 000|False
> 001|True
> 010|True
> 011|False
> 100|True
> 101|False
> 110|False
> 111|True
> Total True: 4

Comment: You handle 3+ orands case wrong: `1 XOR 1 XOR 1` should be `True`, not `111|False`. This is easy to fix: just add `% 2` of the sum to the function. However, this makes it almost identical to @Phillip M. Feldman's answer.

Comment: @AlexPotapenko yeah, you're right.  I've added my new understanding to the answer.

Comment: You now probably have a small typo: it should be `bool(sum(bool(x) for x in orands) % 2)`, otherwise it is always `True` except for all `False` orands due to all non-zero sums casting to `True`. Your previous `== 1` approach is also perfectly valid: `sum(bool(x) for x in orands) % 2 == 1`

Answer (score 1):

XOR is implemented in `operator.xor`.

Comment: operator.xor corresponds to the bitwise operation, which it the one that the original poster doesn't want.

Comment: @kojiro [evidently so!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432842/how-do-you-get-the-logical-xor-of-two-variables-in-python/57203199#comment27750647_11036506)

Answer (score 1):

Just because I haven't seen it mentioned elsewhere, this also does the trick:

```
def logical_xor(a, b):
    return not b if a else bool(b)
```

I'm not sure if it's "better"/more readable/more pythonic than the accepted solution bool(a) != bool(b).

Answer (score -1):

The way that Python handles logic operations can be confusing, so my implementation gives the user the option (by default) of a simple True/False answer.  The actual Python result can be obtained by setting the optional third arg to None.

```
def xor(a, b, true=True, false=False): # set true to None to get actual Python result
    ab1 = a and not b
    ab2 = not a and b
    if bool(ab1) != bool(ab2):
        return (ab1 or ab2) if true is None else true
    else:
        return false
```

Answer (score -1):

The xor implementation

`(False if a else b) if b else a`

returns one of the operands and short-circuits just like `or` and `and`, if possible:

| b\a | ”” | ”foo” |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | ”” | ”foo” |
| 1 | 1 | False |

Answer (score -11):

We can easily find xor of two variables by the using:

```
def xor(a,b):
    return a !=b
```

Example:

> > > xor(True,False)    >>> True

Comment: or `xor("hey", "there")` >>> True, but that's not what we want