# Check if only one variable in a list of variables is set

Tags: python, xor

I'm looking for a simple method to check if only one variable in a list of variables has a True value.
I've looked at this [logical xor post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432842/how-do-you-get-the-logical-xor-of-two-variables-in-python) and is trying to find a way to adapt to multiple variables and only one true.

Example

```
>>>TrueXor(1,0,0)
True

>>>TrueXor(0,0,1)
True

>>>TrueXor(1,1,0)
False

>>>TrueXor(0,0,0,0,0)
False
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There isn't one built in but it's not to hard to roll you own:

```
def TrueXor(*args):
    return sum(args) == 1
```

Since "[b]ooleans are a subtype of plain integers" ([source](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex)) you can sum the list of integers quite easily and you can also pass true booleans into this function as well.

So these two calls are homogeneous:

```
TrueXor(1, 0, 0)
TrueXor(True, False, False)
```

If you want explicit boolean conversion: `sum( bool(x) for x in args ) == 1`.

Comment: I like this -- maybe you can update it to convert the args to bools explicitly?

Comment: I think you mean to write ``sum(bool(a) for a in args) == 1`` -- the variables themselves might not be booleans.

Comment: I just love one-liners. I just learned something new about bools.

Comment: I think the fastest (with explicit conversion) would be only_one = lambda *args: sum(map(bool, args)) == 1

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something - why bool() the arguments when there is an implicit conversion?  I understand that "explicit is better than implicit" but still it doesn't make much sense to me to do an explicit conversion in this case.

Comment: Say the arguments are strings -- in this case, there is no implicit conversion in your function. Same for tuples, lists, dicts, sets... none work with the builtin sum().

Comment: Good point.  I guess I would rather the function explode on bad input rather than use the bool() function and mask a problem.  Still, good point :)

Answer (score 10):

I think the sum-based solution is fine for the given example, but keep in mind that boolean predicates in python always short-circuit their evaluation.  So you might want to consider something more consistent with [all and any](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#all).

```
def any_one(iterable):
    it = iter(iterable)
    return any(it) and not any(it)
```

Comment: Nice. You should explain that the `not any(it)` works on the rest of the items left over by the `any(it)`, for people not that comfortable with iterators.

Comment: There's a healthy discussion of this usage here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16801605/4403872, and here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16522290/4403872

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> def f(*n):
...     n = [bool(i) for i in n]
...     return n.count(True) == 1
...
>>> f(0, 0, 0)
False
>>> f(1, 0, 0)
True
>>> f(1, 0, 1)
False
>>> f(1, 1, 1)
False
>>> f(0, 1, 0)
True
>>>
```

Comment: I think this is the simplest answer, and the only one that is immediately clear.

Comment: I think @Andrew Hare 's answer is the one that fits this question, but this answer better fit my needs. I had 3 variables that can either be False or an integer value and I wanted to make sure that only one variable is an integer and the others are set to False. This one works fine

Answer (score 1):

The question you linked to already provides the solution for two variables. All you have to do is extend it to work on n variables:

```
import operator

def only_one_set(*vars):
    bools = [bool(v) for v in vars]
    return reduce(operator.xor, bools, False)

>>> a, b, c, d, e = False, '', [], 10, -99
>>> only_one_set(a, b, c, d)
True
>>> only_one_set(a, b, c, d, e)
False
```

Comment: As usual, reduce is a false friend: this actually checks if there's an ODD number of true values -- it will be just as happy with 7 or 77 ones as with just 1!

Comment: You're right...though I guess the blame would be more on my faulty logic than `reduce`. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my straightforward approach.  I've renamed it only_one since xor with more than one input is usually a parity checker, not an "only one" checker.

```
def only_one(*args):
    result = False
    for a in args:
        if a:
            if result:
                return False
            else:
                result = True
    return result
```

Testing:

```
>>> only_one(1,0,0)
True
>>> only_one(0,0,1)
True
>>> only_one(1,1,0)
False
>>> only_one(0,0,0,0,0)
False
>>> only_one(1,1,0,1)
False
```