# How to have if statement accept any one of three arguments without all being true in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

So, I am working on a small project. I am making a text-based temperature calculator but I have run into a problem with an if statement in the program, just as the title of this question suggests.

This is the code that I am having issues with.

```
running = True
fahr = "fahrenheit"
cel = "celsius"
kel = "kelvin"
temperatures = [fahr, cel, kel]

while running == True:
    try:
        temperature_type = str.lower(input("What is the current temperature unit you are using? \nFahrenheit, Celsius, or Kelvin?\n"))
    except ValueError:
        print("I do not understand. Please try again.")
        continue
    if temperature_type == any(temperatures) and not all(temperatures):
        break
    else:
        print("Please enter a valid input.")
        continue
```

It seems that there is something wrong with the logic that I am not seeing, and I have tried multiple combinations, even ones that are suggested from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16522111/python-syntax-for-if-a-or-b-or-c-but-not-all-of-them) and none of them seem to work the way I want it to. The way I want it to work is to let the variable temperature_type be equal to only one of the temperatures such as Fahrenheit and then ask another question (which is not shown here). If the variable temperature_type does not equal any of the three, then I want to loop to repeat. The issue I am having is that no matter what I input, it always asks for the temperature. If anyone has an answer I would be thrilled to know what I am doing wrong and I would also love an explanation of the logic because I am not the best with this sort of logic yet. Thanks again for any answers and/or guidance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`any` and `all` return `True` or `False`, not some object that can be compared meaningfully to a `str`. All non-empty `str` are "truthy", so you're checking `if temperature_type == True and not True`, which of course will never pass.

You're desired logic would probably be:

```
if temperature_type in temperatures:
```

It's impossible for someone to enter multiple temperature types in your design, so you don't need any equivalent to the `all` test, you just want to know if the entered string matches one of the three known strings.

Comment: Thank you! This helped out a lot! I really appreciate you (as well and everyone else) for taking the time to answer my question! This makes so much more sense now!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simpler version of the check that simply checks that the input string is one of the valid temperatures. It uses the `in` operator to check that the provided string is *in* `temperatures`.

```
running = True
fahr = "fahrenheit"
cel = "celsius"
kel = "kelvin"
temperatures = [fahr, cel, kel]

while running:
    temperature_type = str.lower(input("What is the current temperature unit you are using? \nFahrenheit, Celsius, or Kelvin?\n"))
    if temperature_type in temperatures:
        break
    print("Please enter a valid input.")
```

Answer (score 0):

OR:

```
while 1:
    if input("What is the current temperature unit you are using? \nFahrenheit, Celsius, or Kelvin?\n").lower() in temperatures:
        break
    print("Please enter a valid input.")
```

Explanation:

`all` and `any` returns `True` or `False` so it will not work so use `in`

I removed `running` because just use `1`

You can do `True` too, see:

```
>>> 1==True
True
```

Comment: if he does it like this he will not have the input saved anywhere and so he will have no way to access it later....

Comment: @AntiMatterDynamite I know, i won't will be still 101's answer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe expand to include all of the scales, and make it the user interface easier.

```
scales = ['F', 'R', 'C', 'K']

while True:
    if input("What temperature scale are you using [F, C, K, R]? ")[0].upper() in scales: break
```

[0]