# What is the pythonic way to determine that two or more boolean evaluations are all False?

Tags: python, syntax, boolean

In a conditional like `if (bool) and (bool):`, what is the cleanest expression that will return `True` if both evaluations are `False`?

I see many options to logically make this work, but they all look messy to me.

Comment: Did you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16522111/python-syntax-for-if-a-or-b-or-c-but-not-all-of-them ? It seems to have good examples

Comment: if (not bool1) and (not bool2) should work, as if not (bool1 or bool2)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python syntax for "if a or b or c but not all of them"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16522111/python-syntax-for-if-a-or-b-or-c-but-not-all-of-them)

Comment: @B.Go, yes. Those are the best options I've seen. Thank you.

Comment: @MyNameIsCaleb, the answer from the link you gave does apply to my question, but the question from that link is not as specific as mine.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `all`:

```
if all(not b for b in [bool_1, bool_2, ..., bool_n]):
# means: if all are not True (False)
```

`any`:

```
if not any([bool_1, bool_2, ..., bool_n]):
# means: if not any of them is True (same as above, logically)
```

Or, `sum` (only with `bool` type, otherwise use `sum(map(bool, [bool_1, ..., bool_n]))`):

```
if sum([bool_1, bool_2, ..., bool_n]) == 0:   #  or, if not sum(...):
# True is 1, False is 0, if sum is 0, then all are 0 (False)
```

Comment: I haven't tried `all` or `any` yet. Thank you. Those look very useful.

Comment: You don't need the genexp with `any`.

Comment: Note that those are not necessarily equivalent. `not (a or b)` will only evaluate `b` is `a` is `False`, whereas `not any(a, b)` will always evaluate both `a` and `b`.

Comment: @tobias_k you're right, but I meant (and said) _logically_ equivalent, which they are.