# How to use `argparse` to set any 2 out of 3 arguments?

Tags: python, argparse

There are three arguments: `A`, `B`, `C`. How can I use `argparse` to allow for any two of them to be set and return an error if all three are set?

If I use the method `add_mutually_exclusive_group`, then I think I can only set one and only one of the three arguments. Is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: You can follow a similar example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16524600/674039

Comment: I don't think `argparse` can do this by itself, you'll need to check that condition yourself.

Comment: Didn't you find the `add_any_2_outof_3_group` command in the docs? :)   Some tests are just too specialize to include in a general purpose tool.