# Logic to test that 3 of 4 are True

Tags: boolean-logic

I want to return `True` if and only if 3 out of 4 boolean values are true.

The closest I've gotten is [`(x ^ y) ^ (a ^ b)`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(x+xor+y)+xor+(a+xor+b)+truth+table):

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: Hmm, the only way I can think of with out mathematical formula is to use count. Good question! :)

Comment: (x ^ y) ^ (a ^ b) can't be correct; (T^F)^(F^F) = T^F = T It returns true when only one is true.

Comment: @NameSpace: But ^ is conjunction, and v is disjunction, isn't it?

Comment: @AneeshKarthikC In the context of this question, it probably means ⊕, which is written as `^` in C and other languages. ∧ is sometimes typed as ^ because it looks similar and the latter appears on keyboards, but it's not the same symbol.

Comment: You idea is not bad, but you must take the negations: `not a ^ not b ^ not c ^ not d` is true when exactly one of the negated values is true. This means, from the original values, exactly one was false.

Comment: What is your **actual problem** behind this details?

Comment: @Ingo not a ^ not b ^ not c ^ not d return true where only one is false AND where 3 are false.

Comment: Are you looking for an answer in a programming language, or in notation with formal logic symbols, or..?

Comment: I would suggest a K-map, but it turns out to be rather unhelpful here:

    0000
    0010
    0101
    0010

Comment: @Wolf Evaluating a poker hand.

Comment: @TimS. Well, preferably something like Java, but symbols are as good.

Comment: The obvious non-count solution is `(!a&&b&&c&&d) || (a&&!b&&c&&d) || (a&&b&&!c&&d) || (a&&b&&c&&!d)`.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map

Comment: Woot, 100th +1!
...but I don't understand what the issue you're actually having is. If it's not a real (as in, actual) issue you're facing, perhaps you can try http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 249, accepted):

I suggest writing the code in a manner that indicates what you mean. If you want 3 values to be true, it seems natural to me that the value 3 appears somewhere.

For instance, in `C++`:

```
if ((int)a + (int)b + (int)c + (int)d == 3)
    ...
```

This is well defined in `C++`: the `standard (§4.7/4)` indicates that converting `bool` to `int` gives the expected values 0 or 1.

In Java and C#, you can use the following construct:

```
if ((a?1:0) + (b?1:0) + (c?1:0) + (d?1:0) == 3)
    ...
```

Comment: This is a good answer. This looks like a case of that X/Y thing. "He wants to do X using Y, but does not know how to do Y. Instead of asking X, he asks Y." Unless he is designing a logic circuit or something like that (and then he would be in the wrong site), the best way to do this is in a way that is **readable**.

Comment: @NothingsImpossible There is nothing XY about the question. It's a clear and straight-forward question about solving a reasonably common problem in programming. The Y is irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks! This is really what I _meant_ to do, but my idea was so clumsy  that I reached for boolean logic.

Comment: `if (!!a + !!b + !!c + !!d == 3)` is easier to write, although I don't know whether compilers optimize this or not

Comment: Actually, this does not even care about the question by OP.

Comment: Note that in c++ the cast from bool to int is not necessary.

Answer (score 90):

#1: Using a branching ?:  3 or 4 operations

```
A ^ B ? C & D : ( C ^ D ) & A
```

#2 Non-Branching, 7 operations

```
(A ^ B ^ C ^ D) & ((A & B) | (C & D))
```

Back when I use to profile everything, I found [non-branching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_prediction) solutions were quite a bit quicker operation-for-operation as the CPU could predict the code path better, and execute more operations in tandem.  There is about 50% less work in the branching statement here though.

Comment: +1 - while the other answers are better for most programming languages, your #2 is the best answer in pure boolean logic.

Comment: [Wolframalpha truth table](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28A+xor+B+xor+C+xor+D%29+and+%28%28A+and+B%29+or+%28C+and+D%29%29+truth+table) for #2

Answer (score 69):

If this had been Python, I would have written

```
if [a, b, c, d].count(True) == 3:
```

Or

```
if [a, b, c, d].count(False) == 1:
```

Or

```
if [a, b, c, d].count(False) == True:
# In Python True == 1 and False == 0
```

Or

```
print [a, b, c, d].count(0) == 1
```

Or

```
print [a, b, c, d].count(1) == 3
```

Or

```
if a + b + c + d == 3:
```

Or

```
if sum([a, b, c, d]) == 3:
```

All these work, since Booleans are subclasses of integers in Python.

```
if len(filter(bool, [a, b, c, d])) == 3:
```

Or, inspired by this [neat trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16801605/1903116),

```
data = iter([a, b, c, d])
if not all(data) and all(data):
```

Comment: +1 This solves the problem by correctly translating it into Python.

Comment: This is slightly dangerous because people may return any non-zero integer in a boolean context in python. The old C trick works in python too: `a=5;not not a == 1`. The disadvantage of not having a real boolean type.

Comment: @Voo We also have [`bool`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bool) :)

Comment: @thefourtheye Ah yes true, much nicer than the double negation trick/hack.

Comment: JS version: `if ([x,y,z,w].filter(x => x).length == 3)` (note: it requires the [arrow function syntax from ES6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/arrow_functions).)

Comment: Or...or....or....There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it. :-/ :-)

Answer (score 53):

Long but very simple, (disjuntive) normal form:

```
 (~a & b & c & d) | (a & ~b & c & d) | (a & b & ~c & d) | (a & b & c & ~d)
```

It may be simplified but that requires more thinking :P

Comment: @Ben that just gives you various normal forms of it, which this already is in (DNF).

Comment: How about `(a & b & (c ^ d)) | ((a ^ b) & c & d)`?

Comment: Yes, @immibis, according to Wolfram Alpha its DNF is the formula I've written so it's the same boolean function.

Comment: +1 because I think someone reading the code will understand what is being attempted quicker than with other answers.

Answer (score 34):

Not sure it is simpler, but maybe.

[`((x xor y) and (a and b)) or ((x and y) and (a xor b))`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x+xor+y%29+and+%28a+and+b%29+or+%28x+and+y%29+and+%28a+xor+b%29+truth+table)

Comment: damn! They should've given option multi up-vote an answer! Especially using wolfram alpha to prove your answer right is very good thing!

Answer (score 23):

If you want to use this logic in a programming language, my suggestion is

```
bool test(bool a, bool b, bool c, bool d){
    int n1 = a ? 1 : 0;
    int n2 = b ? 1 : 0;
    int n3 = c ? 1 : 0;
    int n4 = d ? 1 : 0;

    return n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 == 3;
}
```

Or if you want, you can put all of these in a single line:

```
return (a ? 1 : 0) + (b ? 1 : 0) + (C ? 1 : 0) + (d ? 1 : 0) == 3;
```

Also you can generalize this problem to `n of m`  :

```
bool test(bool *values, int n, int m){
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < m; i += 1){
        sum += values[i] ? 1 : 0;
    }
    return sum == n;
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it. Readability trumps cleverness, every time. +1

Answer (score 20):

This answer depends on the system of representation, but if 0 is the only value interpreted as false, and `not(false)` always returns the same numeric value, then `not(a) + not(b) + not(c) + not(d) = not(0)` should do the trick.

Answer (score 18):

Keeping in mind that SO if for programming questions, rather than mere logical problems, the answer obviously depends on the choice of a programming language. Some languages support features that are uncommon to others.

For example, in C++ you could test your conditions with:

```
(a + b + c + d) == 3
```

This should be the fastest way to do the check in languages that support automatic (low-level) conversion from boolean to integer types. But again, there is no general answer for that problem.

Comment: This is the answer I was going to post. One thing to add though, depending on the programming language used, the answer you want would be -3. In VB, True = -1.

Answer (score 12):

The best I can do is [`((x ^ y) ^ (a ^ b)) && ((a || x) && (b || y))`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x+xor+y%29+xor+%28a+xor+b%29+and+%28a+or+x%29+and+%28b+or+y%29+truth+table)

Comment: What means *best* to you?

Comment: Interesting. Took the op's solution and just shaved off the bad cases

Answer (score 11):

To check at least `n` out of all `Boolean` are true, ( n must be less than or equal to total number of `Boolean` :p)

```
if (((a ? 1:0) + (b ? 1:0 ) + (c ? 1:0) + (d ? 1:0 )) >= n) {
    // do the rest
}
```

**Edit** : After @Cruncher's comment

To check 3 `boolean` out of 4

```
if (((a ? 1:0) + (b ? 1:0 ) + (c ? 1:0) + (d ? 1:0 )) == 3) {
    // do the rest
}
```

Another one :

[`((c & d) & (a ^ b)) | ((a & b) & (c ^ d))`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%28c%20and%20d%29%20and%20%28a%20xor%20b%29%29%20or%20%28%28a%20and%20b%29%20and%20%28c%20xor%20d%29%29%20truth%20table) ([Details](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%28c%20and%20d%29%20and%20%28a%20xor%20b%29%29%20or%20%28%28a%20and%20b%29%20and%20%28c%20xor%20d%29%29))

Comment: OP wants exactly n, not at least n. But that's an easy change from this solution

Comment: @Wolf that question belongs to StackUnderflow.com :p

Answer (score 11):

```
((a xor b) xor (c xor d)) and ((a or b) and (c or d))
```

The fist expression searchs for 1 or 3 `true`'s out of 4. The second one eliminates 0 or 1 (and sometimes 2) `true`'s out of 4.

Answer (score 11):

Java 8, filter out the false values, and count the remaining true values:

```
public static long count(Boolean... values) {
    return Arrays.stream(values).filter(t -> t).count();
}
```

Then you can use it as follows:

```
if (3 == count(a, b, c, d)) {
    System.out.println("There... are... THREE... lights!");
}
```

Easily generalizes to checking for `n` of `m` items being true.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a way you could solve it in C# with LINQ:

```
bool threeTrue = new[] { a, b, x, y }.Count(x => x) == 3;
```

Answer (score 10):

That is the symmetric Boolean function `S₃(4)`. A symmetric Boolean function is a boolean function which only depends on the quantity of inputs set, but doesn't depend on which inputs they are. Knuth mentions functions of this type in section 7.1.2 in Volume 4 of The Art of Computer Programming.

`S₃(4)` can be computed with 7 operations as follows:

```
(x && y && (a || b)) ^ ((x || y) && a && b)
```

Knuth shows that this is optimal, meaning that you cannot do this in less than 7 operations using the normal operators: `&&, || , ^, <,` and `>`.

However if you want to use this in a language which uses `1` for true and `0` for false, you can also use addition easily:

```
x + y + a + b == 3
```

which makes your intention quite clear.

Answer (score 9):

```
(a && b && (c xor d)) || (c && d && (a xor b))
```

From a pure logic point of view this is what I came up with.

By the pigeon hole principle, if exactly 3 are true, then either a and b is true, or c and d is true. Then its just a matter of anding each of those cases with exactly one of the other 2.

[Wolfram truth table](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28a%20and%20b%20and%20%28c%20xor%20d%29%29%20%7C%7C%20%28c%20and%20d%20and%20%28a%20xor%20b%29%29%20truth%20table)

Comment: This is equivalent to NameSpace's second solution.

Comment: @Brilliand Seems different to me. His xors all together to get all 3's or 1's, then excludes the ones with 1 by requiring at least one from 2 distinct groups. (summarized as 1 or 3 and at least 2). Mine requires both from one of the distinct groups, and then exactly one from the other group.

Comment: If you meant equivalent in the sense that `mine <=> his` then I don't know what to say as this would be expected.

Comment: I guess I meant that this answer is good in exactly the same way that NameSpace's second solution is good, without adding anything new that NameSpace's (earlier) answer didn't cover.  Well, I'll upvote anyway.

Answer (score 8):

If you use a logic visualization tool like Karnaugh Maps, you see that this is a problem where you can't avoid a full blown logic term if you want to write it in one if (...) line. Lopina showed it already, it's not possible to write it simpler. You can factor out a bit, but it will stay hard to read for you AND for the machine.

Counting solutions are not bad and they show what you are really after. How you do the counting efficiently depends on your programming language. The array solutions with Python oder LinQ are nice to look at, but beware, this is SLOW. Wolf's (a+b+x+y)==3 will work nicely and fast, but only if your language equates "true" with 1. If "true" is represented by -1, you will have to test for -3 :)

If your language uses true booleans, you could try to program it explicitly (I use != as XOR test):

```
if (a)
{
    if (b)
        return (x != y);    // a,b=true, so either x or y must be true
    else
        return (x && y);     // a=true, b=false, so x AND y must be true
}
else
{
    if (b)
        return (x && y);    // a=false, b=true, so x and y must be true
    else
        return false;       // a,b false, can't get 3 of 4
}
```

"x != y" works only if x,y are of a boolean type. If they are some other type where 0 is false and everything else is true, this can fail. Then use a boolean XOR, or ( (bool)x != (bool)y ), or write "if (x) return (y==false) else return (y==true);", which is a bit more work for the computer.

If your programming language provides the ternary ?: operator, you can shorten it to

```
if (a)
    return b ? (x != y) : (x && y);
else
    return b ? (x && y) : false;
```

which keeps a bit of readability, or cut it aggressively to

```
return a ? (b ? (x != y) : (x && y)) : (b ? (x && y) : false);
```

This code does exactly three logic tests (state of a, state of b, comparison of x and y) and should be faster than most of the other answers here. But you need to comment it, or you won't understand it after 3 months :)

Answer (score 8):

There are a lot of good answers here; here is an alternate formulation which no one else has posted yet:

```
 a ? (b ? (c ^ d) : (c && d)) : (b && c && d)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but can you please add some commentary as to how it works? Thanks.

Comment: (Sorry to pick on you, I was given it as a review audit. At least I passed.. :))

Answer (score 7):

Similar to the first answer, but pure Java:

```
int t(boolean b) {
    return (b) ? 1 : 0;
}

if (t(x) + t(y) + t(a) + t(b) == 3) return true;
return false;
```

I prefer counting them as integers because it makes for more readable code.

Answer (score 7):

In **Python**, to see how many of an iterable of elements are True, use `sum` (it's quite straightforward):

**Setup**

```
import itertools

arrays = list(itertools.product(*[[True, False]]*4))
```

**Actual Test**

```
for array in arrays:
    print(array, sum(array)==3)
```

**Output**

```
(True, True, True, True) False
(True, True, True, False) True
(True, True, False, True) True
(True, True, False, False) False
(True, False, True, True) True
(True, False, True, False) False
(True, False, False, True) False
(True, False, False, False) False
(False, True, True, True) True
(False, True, True, False) False
(False, True, False, True) False
(False, True, False, False) False
(False, False, True, True) False
(False, False, True, False) False
(False, False, False, True) False
(False, False, False, False) False
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're after the on-the-paper (non-programming) solution, then K-maps and Quine-McCluskey algorithms are what you're after, they help you minify your boolean function.

In your case, the result is

```
y = (x̄3 ^ x2 ^ x1 ^ x0) ∨ (x3 ^ x̄2 ^ x1 ^ x0) ∨ (x3 ^ x2 ^ x̄1 ^ x0) ∨ (x3 ^ x2 ^ x1 ^ x̄0)
```

If you want to do this programmatically, non-fixed amount of variables and a custom "threshold", then simply iterating thru a list of boolean values and counting occurrences of "true" is pretty simple and straightforward.

Comment: What does the bar overhead mean? I notice its moving down the list.

Comment: @NameSpace It is one of the IMO too many notations people use to express "not".

Answer (score 5):

> I want to return true if and only if 3 out of 4 boolean values are true.

Given the 4 boolean values, a, b, x, y, this task translates into the following C statement:

```
return (a+b+x+y) == 3;
```

Comment: Nice trap. This assumes `true` equals 1. This is not true (no pun intended) in all languages/cases. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/12/22/329884.aspx

Comment: @JensG You're right: I make this assumption explicit. Thx :)

Answer (score 4):

```
((a^b)^(x^y))&((a|b)&(x|y))
```

is what you want. Basically I took your code and added checking if actually 3 are true and not 3 are false.

Answer (score 4):

A programming question without an answer involving recursion? *Inconceivable!*

There are enough "exactly 3 out of 4 trues" answers, but here's a generalised (Java) version for "exactly m out of n trues" (otherwise recursion isn't really worth it) just because you can:

```js
public static boolean containsTrues(boolean[] someBooleans,
    int anIndex, int truesExpected, int truesFoundSoFar) {
  if (anIndex >= someBooleans.length) {
    return truesExpected == truesFoundSoFar; // reached end
  }
  int falsesExpected = someBooleans.length - truesExpected;
  boolean currentBoolean = someBooleans[anIndex];
  int truesFound = truesFoundSoFar + (currentBoolean ? 1 : 0);
  if (truesFound > truesExpected) {
    return false;
  }
  if (anIndex - truesFound > falsesExpected) {
    return false; // too many falses
  }
  return containsTrues(someBooleans, anIndex + 1, truesExpected,
      truesFound);
}
```

This could be called with something like:

```js
 boolean[] booleans = { true, false, true, true, false, true, true, false };
 containsTrues(booleans, 0, 5, 0);
```

which should return `true` (because 5 of 8 values were true, as expected). Not quite happy with the words "trues" and "falses", but can't think of a better name right now.... Note that the recursion stops when too many `true` *or* too many `false` values have been found.

Comment: @FélixSaparelli: Not sure "truth" applies here... it would sound like you're happy with just one `true`. Maybe something like `containsNumberOfTrueValues()`. As an aside: Smalltalk's naming would be much more suitable for this, though: `doesArray: someBooleans startingAt: anIndex containNumberOfTrueValues: anExpectedNumber foundSofar: aNumberFoundSoFar`. Probably too long for some Java devs' tastes, but Smalltalkers are never afraid of proper naming ;-)

Comment: That was mostly humorous. And `containsTruth` means "contains some undisclosed amount of truth", literally, so I believe it's quite okay.

Answer (score 3):

Since readability is a big concern, you could use a descriptive function call (wrapping any of the suggested implementations).  If this calculation needs to be done in multiple places, a function call is the best way to achieve reuse, and makes it clear exactly what you are doing.

```
bool exactly_three_true_from(bool cond1, bool cond2, bool cond3, bool cond4)
{
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In PHP, making it more dynamic (just in case you change number of conditions, etc.):

```
$min = 6;
$total = 10;

// create our boolean array values
$arr = array_map(function($a){return mt_rand(0,1)>0;},range(1,$total));

// the 'check'
$arrbools = array_map(function($a){return (int)$a;},$arr);
$conditionMet = array_sum($arrbools)>=$min;

echo $conditionMet ? "Passed" : "Failed";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(((a AND b) OR (x AND y)) AND ((a XOR b) OR (x XOR y)))
```

While I could show that this is a good solution, Sam Hocevar's answer is easy both to write and understand later.  In my book that makes it better.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some c# code I just wrote because you have inspired me:

It takes any amount of arguments and will tell you if n of them are true.

```cs
    static bool boolTester(int n, params bool[] values)
    {
        int sum = 0;           

        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
        {
            if (values[i] == true)
            {
                sum += 1;
            }                
        }
        if( sum == n)
        {
            return true;
        }            
        return false;                
    }
```

and you call it like so:

```cs
        bool a = true;
        bool b = true;
        bool c = true;
        bool d = false;            

        bool test = false;
        test = boolTester(3, a, b, c, d);
```

So you can now test 7/9 or 15/100 as you will.