# How to force one keyword in python function

Tags: python, function, methods, arguments, keyword

I am implementing a function with three keywords. The default value for each keyword is `None`, but I need to force the user to pass at least one keyword. The reason why I want to use keywords is that the keyword names `a, b` and `c` are descriptive, and will help the user to figure out what does he need to pass to `method`. How do I achieve my task?

```
def method(a=None, b=None, c=None):

    if a!=None:
        func_a(a)
    elif b!=None:
        func_b(b)
    elif c!=None:
        func_c(c)
    else:
        raise MyError('Don\'t be silly, user - please!')
```

In the above example, assume of course that `a, b` and `c` have different attributes. The obvious solution would be:

```
def method(x):
    if is_instance(x, A):
        func_a(x)
    elif is_instance(x, B):
        func_b(x)
    [...]
```

But the problem is that as I said I want to use the keyword names `a, b` and `c` to help the user understand what he does need to pass to `method`!

Is there a more *pythonic* way to achieve the result?

Comment: Which Python version is this? In Python 3.4 you can use single-dispatch generic functions for this: http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0443/

Comment: @SimeonVisser Thanks for the link, that's very interesting! Unfortunately I am stuck with python 2.7. I think I want overloading, that's it!

Comment: @SimeonVisser Thanks for the link, too. Everyday you learn something new.

Comment: [related, but with correlated arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28604741/321973)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this expression to evaluate that at least one argument is passed

```
if not (a or b or c):
    raise MyError
```

Comment: This fails if `a`, `b` or `c` can assume a false, but valid value (e.g. `0` or any empty container).

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) to raise an error early:

```
def foo(a=None, b=None, c=None):
    if all(x is None for x in (a, b, c)):
        raise ValueError('You need to set at least *one* of a, b, or c')

    if a is not None:
        func_a(a)
    # etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use decorator, simulating the Contract programming paradigm.

```
def check_params(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        a = kwargs.get('a', None)
        b = kwargs.get('b', None)
        c = kwargs.get('c', None)
        if (a == b == c == None):
            raise Exception("Set one of a, b or c is mandatory.")
        else:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


@check_params
def foo(a=None, b=None, c=None):
    print("Ok")


foo(a=4)  # This will print ok.
foo()     # This will rise an exception.
```

Comment: Interesting approach, though you could generalize the decorator using [`inspect.getargspec`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/218709/321973) and [`all`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22994928/321973)

Answer (score 0):

Note that a call such as `method(b="something", a="otherthing")` would return `func_a(a)`, and *not* `func_b(b)`, which the user might expect. In fact, it would be better to make sure [one and only one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1183702/163) keyword is *not* `None` (see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16801322/321973)), for which it would probably make more sense for the user to simply directly call the respective methods (though you might want to call them `method_from_a` etc. then).