# XOR'ing each bit of a binary string in Python

Tags: python, binary

I have two binary **strings** (not integer) for example `0101` and `0010`, I need to XOR these two binary strings and then XOR the each bit of the result again. XOR of these two results in `0111`, now I want to achieve the result `0 xor 1 xor 1 xor 1`. How can I achieve it in python?

I have XORed the two strings in result variable, now I need to find the XOR of each bit in result

```
a = "0101"
b = "0010"
result = []
for x, y in zip(a, b):
    if x == y:
        result.append('0')
    else:
        result.append('1')
final = []
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: `reduce` , define a function...

Comment: How are your "binary strings" represented ?

Comment: Please don't post solutions into questions. Also as I mentioned below you mixed the two approaches. If you create `result` as an int, why transform it to a string? You can easily do a parity check on an int

Comment: @Tomerikoo Actually my solution was wrong for my case. I shouldn't use integers because my strings can be up to 2K bits long. That was why I was avoiding integers. Thanks anyway

Comment: Do you actually need that XOR of the two strings, or only the final XOR result (i.e., one bit)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Working with strings

You can use the same logic you used on two inputs, to [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) a single input:

```py
from functools import reduce

final = reduce(lambda x, y: '0' if x == y else '1', result)
```

---

#### Working with ints

Alternatively, you can just transform the inputs to ints by using [`int(x, 2)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int). So you can have:

```
result = int(a, 2) ^ int(b, 2)
```

And now you just need to bit-wise XOR `result`. That is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7463656/is-there-any-xor-bit-reduction-operand-or-function) and is basically a parity check which can be easily done (Python >= 3.10) with

```
final = result.bit_count() & 1
```

Comment: Can you check my last edit please? I have a problem with reduce.

Comment: Because you used `reduce` on the integer result. You mixed the two ways. Stick with one