# Changing Value Through Button or Checkbox in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

My Whole Program is Working in a Loop like this

```
myWindow = Tk()
myWindow.title("Live Data")
myWindow.geometry("500x600")

def my_mainloop():
    statements....
    myWindow.after(1000, my_mainloop)

myWindow.after(1000, my_mainloop)
myWindow.mainloop()
```

I want to implement something(button/checkbox), which is changing a value in variable
like 0 and 1

so i can use this value (0/1) in this infinite loop to code my logic

A Click will change value to 1 and then another click will change value to 0.

Thank you.

Comment: @Jordan that is related running a While True loop in Tkinter, and yes the program reaches the last line, even i don't know how, but it does.

Comment: @stovfl i don't want to toggle value through code, i want to toggle through GUI

Comment: @stovfl that statement represents that all the coding is there, end_user wants to  toggle values through GUI, not by opening code and changing the value there

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to toggle a value in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8381735/how-to-toggle-a-value-in-python)

Answer (score -1):

my example:

```
def change_value(*arg):
    value = 1
button(myWindow, text, command=change_value)
```

Comment: i am new to tkinter but dont you have to use .pack  ?