# Flip a boolean value without referencing it twice

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking for a short syntax that would look somewhat like `x *= -1` where `x` is a number, but for booleans, if it even exists. It should behave like `b = not(b)`. The interested of this is being able to flip a boolean in a single line when the variable name is very long.

For example, if you have a program where you can turn on|off lamps in a house, you want to avoid writing the full thing:

```
self.lamps_dict["kitchen"][1] = not self.lamps_dict["kitchen"][1]
```

Comment: you mean `True == not False`?

Comment: `b = not b`...?

Comment: @norok2 The length. Either you can make it a one-liner and have to write the full name of `b` twice, or you can save a temp value beforehand and do `value = b; b = not value` which is even worse.

Comment: You could use a temp variable differently, like `lamp = self.lamps_dict["kitchen"]; lamp[1] = not lamp[1]`. But I prefer Asocia's answer :-)

Comment: Related: [How to toggle a value in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8381735/7851470).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [xor operator (^)](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations):

```
x = True
x ^= True
print(x) # False
x ^= True
print(x) # True
```

Edit: As suggested by [Guimoute](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9282844/guimoute) in the comments, you can even shorten this by using `x ^= 1` but it will change the type of `x` to an integer which might not be what you are looking for, although it will work without any problem where you use it as a condition directly, `if x:` or `while x:` etc.