# How to make a toggle button

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make a program that toggles the background color from black to white when I press the space bar.

Does anyone know what is wrong with my code:

```
import pygame, sys

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
wn_size = (800, 600)
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(wn_size)

bg_change = False

running = True
while running:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                if bg_change:
                    bg_change = True
                else:
                    bg_change = False

    if bg_change == True:
        screen.fill(255,255,255)
    else:
        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: To toggle a switch, you dont need to do ` if bg_change: bg_change = True else: bg_change = False`. Instead do `bg_change = Not bg_change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake is in the lines:

> ```py
> if bg_change:
>    bg_change = True
> else:
>    bg_change = False
> ```

This code doesn't actually do anything. If `bg_change` is `True` it is set `True` and if `bg_change` is `False` it is set `False`. What you actually want to do is:

```py
if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
    if bg_change:
        bg_change = False
    else:
        bg_change = True
```

You can simplify the code with the `not` operator. `not` inverts (toggles) a Boolean variable:

```py
if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
    bg_change = not bg_change
```

---

[`fill`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.fill) has a single argument, which can be a tuple with the RGB color values:

<s>`screen.fill(255,255,255)`</s>

```py
screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
```

---

Complete code:

```py
import pygame, sys

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
wn_size = (800, 600)
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(wn_size)

bg_change = False

running = True
while running:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                bg_change = not bg_change

    if bg_change == True:
        screen.fill((255,255,255))
    else:
        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you added three different parameters instead of a tuple in `screen.fill(255,255,255)`.

You can fix this by just adding another layer of brackets, like this: `screen.fill((255,255,255))`.

The if statement should look like this:

```
    if bg_change:
        screen.fill((255,255,255))
    else:
        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
```

EDIT: As @JoeFerndz mentioned, you should also change `if bg_change == True` to just `if bg_change` since adding `== True` is redundant.

Comment: just check for `if bg_change` as its same as `== True`

Comment: That's true, I'll edit my answer right now to include that. Thanks for letting me know! @JoeFerndz

Answer (score 0):

You can use basic toggle switch to change the values.

Here are two options:

## 1: boolean switch

```
bg_change = False

running = True

while running:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                bg_change = not bg_change

    if bg_change:
        screen.fill((255,255,255))
    else:
        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
```

## 2: set fill value as toggle

```
t = 255 ^ 0
x = 0
x ^= t #x is set to 255 first. If you want to start with 0, comment this line

running = True

while running:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                x ^= t

    screen.fill((x,x,x))
```

Here's how this works:

```
>>> t = 255 ^ 0
>>> x ^= t
>>> x
255
>>> x ^= t
>>> x
0
>>> x ^= t
>>> x
255
```

Every time you have to switch, the value is toggled automatically. So you don't have to worry about the toggle switch. You are using the value of x to toggle.

For more options on toggle, see the impressive solution written up by @Raymond Hettinger in the post [How to toggle a value in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8381735/how-to-toggle-a-value-in-python)

Comment: `Not` is not Python. Python is case senitive.

Comment: sorry, it should be `not` not `Not` :) Edited the answer. Thanks for catching that. Never thought I will write 3 not in one sentence :)

Comment: Using the value of `x` itself to make the toggle overloads the utility of the variable. I'd suggest writing a `Toggle` class if you really want such a tool.