# Creating a BST and insert function in Python

Tags: python, insert, nodes, binary-search-tree

I have created a BST using Python and am having issues with the insert function. I can insert one value, but then when I try to insert again it does not work properly. In particular, I get an error on the _insert function that there is no data attribute for a Nonetype object, although the object should be the created root. Here is my implementation:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data, left=None, right=None):
        self.data=data
        self.left=left
        self.right=right        
    def setdata(self,data):
        self.data=data
    def hasLeft(self):
        return self.left 
    def hasRight(self):
        return self.right
class BST():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root=None
    def insert(self, data):
        if self.root:
            self._insert(data, self.root)
        else:
            self.root=Node(data)

    def _insert(self, data, curr):
        if data<curr.data:
            if curr.hasLeft:
                self._insert(data, curr.left)
            else:
                curr.left=Node(data)
        if data>curr.data:
            if curr.hasRight:
                self._insert(data, curr.right)
            else:
                curr.right=Node(data)

tree=BST()
print tree.root
tree.insert(1)
print tree.root.data
tree.insert(3) # error occurs here
print tree.root.data
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#12>", line 1, in <module>
    tree.insert(3)
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 6, in insert
    self._insert(data, self.root)
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 18, in _insert
    self._insert(data, curr.right)
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 11, in _insert
    if data<curr.data:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data'
```

Comment: I notice you've opened a new question; did my answer help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The traceback shows you what happens:

```
tree.insert(3)
```

Your starting call; so far, so good. `if self.root:` (note: should be `if self.root is not None:`, see e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26778777/3001761)) evaluates truthy, so it calls:

```
self._insert(data, self.root)
```

here `data > curr.data` and `curr.hasRight` both evaluate truthy. **Why?!** Because you *aren't calling the method*; although the `return` value of that method would evaluate falsey, *the method itself doesn't*.

That should be:

```
if curr.hasRight() is not None:
              # ^ note parentheses 
                 # ^ and use of 'is' again
```

After that, as `curr.right is None`,

```
self._insert(data, curr.right)
```

is bound to fail, as `curr` will be `None`:

```
    if data<curr.data:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data'
```

right on cue.

---

Note that it would be neater to handle `None` properly in `Node`, too, making `hasLeft` and `hasRight` return boolean, rather than the node or `None`:

```
def hasLeft(self):
    return self.left is not None
```

then in `BST`, simply:

```
if curr.hasLeft():
```