# Given 2 int values, return True if one is negative and other is positive

Tags: python, python-3.x, return, logical-operators

```
def logical_xor(a, b): # for example, -1 and 1
    print (a < 0) # evaluates to True
    print (b < 0) # evaluates to False
    print (a < 0 != b < 0) # EVALUATES TO FALSE! why??? it's True != False
    return (a < 0 != b < 0) # returns False when it should return True

print ( logical_xor(-1, 1) ) # returns FALSE!

# now for clarification

print ( True != False) # PRINTS TRUE!
```

Could someone explain what is happening? I'm trying to make a one liner:

```
lambda a, b: (a < 0 != b < 0)
```

Comment: There's a lesson to be learned here: Use parentheses. Or, alternatively, use `print (a*b < 0)`.

Comment: `return math.copysign(1, a) != math.copysign(1, b)`

Comment: `print ( True != False) # PRINTS TRUE!` why are you so surprised by that? It _is_ true that true is not equal to false.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar: The OP is *not* surprised by that; it's the behavior (s)he originally expected.

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

All comparison operators in Python have the [same precedence.](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#not-in) In addition, Python does chained comparisons. Thus,

```
(a < 0 != b < 0)
```

breaks down as:

```
(a < 0) and (0 != b) and (b < 0)
```

If any one of these is false, the total result of the expression will be `False`.

What you want to do is evaluate each condition separately, like so:

```
(a < 0) != (b < 0)
```

Other variants, from comments:

```
(a < 0) is not (b < 0) # True and False are singletons so identity-comparison works

(a < 0) ^ (b < 0) # bitwise-xor does too, as long as both sides are boolean

(a ^ b < 0) # or you could directly bitwise-xor the integers; 
            # the sign bit will only be set if your condition holds
            # this one fails when you mix ints and floats though

(a * b < 0) # perhaps most straightforward, just multiply them and check the sign
```

Comment: Note that `(a < 0) ^ (b < 0)` also works, and it's using the xor operator. :) Alternatively, `(a < 0) is not (b < 0)`, since `True` and `False` are singletons, although some might object to that syntax: see here for a discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9494404/4014959

Comment: `^` for *xor* does work if booleans are compared but it won't work for all values like `and` and `or` would...

Comment: OP specifically tagged Python 3.x so I linked to Python 3 manuals.

Comment: I personally like a * b < 0, but one needs to keep in mind that in other languages this can cause integer overflow

Comment: @OverlordAlex: Why could it not cause integer overflow in Python?

Comment: @supercat Python integers are unlimited precision.

Comment: @supercat, to expand on tzaman's answer, python automatically promotes integers to longs when they would overflow, and longs in python are unlimited length (restricted only by available memory). At worst you'll get a float where you might expect an int. In python 3 there aren't any integers/longs, but rather a hybrid general "number", that is arbitrary length, so you dont even have to worry about long vs int

Comment: @OverlordAlex: That makes sense.  On the other hand, I was just noticing that while the OP's code seems to have been trying to identify if one number is negative and one number is non-negative, your formula tests for the condition described in the question title.  If the question title relates what's actually desired, I don't remember if Python has a function to convert values into +1/0/-1 based on whether they're pos/neg/zero, but if so, perhaps applying that to the operands before the multiplication might be a good idea.

Comment: @supercat: Unfortunately python doesn't have a sign() method. One was proposed for the math package, but there wasn't agreement on edge-cases, so it wasn't integrated (according to a quick google). A workaround is using cmp(number, 0), which will return +1/0/-1. This would indeed work for the question

Answer (score 7):

<s>Your code doesn't work as intended because `!=` takes higher [precedence](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) than `a < 0` and `b < 0`. As itzmeontv suggests in his answer, you can simply decide the precedence yourself by surrounding logical components with parentheses:</s>

```
(a < 0) != (b < 0)
```

Your code attempts to evaluate `a < (0 != b) < 0`

**[EDIT]**

As tzaman rightly points out, the operators have the same precedence, but your code is attempting to evaluate `(a < 0) and (0 != b) and (b < 0)`. Surrounding your logical components with parentheses will resolve this:

```
(a < 0) != (b < 0)
```

Operator precedence: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

Comparisons (i.a. chaining): https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#not-in

Comment: They're actually the **same** precedence; the failure is because it's treated as a chained comparison. See [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in).

Comment: @Xis88: Yes, it's equivalent to  `(a < 0) and (0 != b) and (b < 0)`.

Comment: Op specifically tagged Python 3 so please link to Python 3 manuals.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this

```
return (a < 0) != (b < 0)
```

> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., x < y <= z is equivalent to x < y and y <= z, except that y is evaluated only once (but in both cases z is not evaluated at all when x < y is found to be false).

So it becomes

```
(a < 0) and (0 != b) and (b < 0)
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#not-in

Comment: May be it of part of precedence of `!=` and `<`

Comment: `<>` is not "considered obsolescent", it was removed from Python 3.0 altogether.

Comment: (do note that OP tagged the question with [python-3.x])

Answer (score 0):

In Python, comparison operators are of the same precedence, and they are non-associative. There is a separate rule for sequences of comparison operators, the chaining rule. [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#not-in) states about that:

> if `a, b, c, ..., y, z` are expressions and `op1, op2, ..., opN` are comparison operators, then a `op1 b op2 c ... y opN z` is equivalent to `a op1 b and b op2 c and ... y opN z`, except that each expression is evaluated at most once.

Further, `a op1 b and b op2 c and ... y opN z` evaluates left to right.

```
 a < 0 and 0 != b and b < 0
```

`a < 0` will evaluated to `False`, and the further evaluation will be stopped due to [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). So, the whole expression will be evaluated as `False`.

Comment: This is wrong! The documentation you're quoting right there states that the comparisons are chained. *NOT* the same thing as left-associative.