# True False Toggle

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a function that switches a variable from True to False, or vice versa.  I don't want 2 functions, one for true to false, and one for false to true, I just want one function that toggles a variable between True and False.

```
var = True
def func(x):
    #CODE
print var #SHOULD PRINT FALSE
```

any ideas?

Comment: what about `return not x`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use of True, False, and None as return values in python functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9494404/use-of-true-false-and-none-as-return-values-in-python-functions)

Answer (score 3):

If you really want a function, probably the easiest thing to do is

```
def func(x):
    return not x

var = True
var = func(var)
print var
```

otherwise simply negate the variable itself

```
var = True
var = not var
print var
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def func(b):
    return not b
```

Should do it.  Returns `True` if `b` is `False`, and vice versa.