# Python error: subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command returned non-zero exit status 1

Tags: python, command-line, subprocess

I need to count the lines of a shell-command output in python script.

This function works fine in case there is output, but in case the output is empty, it gives an error as explained in the error output.
I tried to avoid that using an `if` statement in case the output of the command is `None`, but that didn't help.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess

lines_counter=0
func="nova list | grep Shutdown "
data=subprocess.check_output(func, shell=True)
if data is True:
       for line in data.splitlines():
               lines_counter +=1
print lines_counter
```

Error output:

```
data=subprocess.check_output(func, shell=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 573, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'nova list | grep Shutdown ' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `grep` command you're running exits with exit status `1` if it doesn't match anything. That non-zero exit code causes `check_output` to raise an exception (that's what the "check" part of its name means).

If you don't want a failed match to raise an exception, consider using `subprocess.getoutput` instead of `check_output`. Or you could change your command to avoid non-zero exit codes:

```
func = "nova list | grep Shutdown || true"
```

Comment: But subprocess.getoutput seems to exist only for python3. (Not mentionned in python2 doc)

Answer (score 1):

That is how it worked 
As described in first solution :
The grep command exits with exit status 1 if it doesn't match anything. That non-zero exit code causes check_output to raise an exception (that's what the "check" part of its name means).

```
func = "nova list | grep Shutdown || true"
```

The code :

```
  lines_counter=0
    func="nova list | grep Shutdown || true"
    try:
        data = subprocess.check_output(func, shell=True)
    except Exception:
        data = None
    for line in data():
            lines_counter +=1
    print lines_counter
```

Answer (score 0):

You can surround the `subprocess` invocation by a try-except block:

```
try:
    data = subprocess.check_output(func, shell=True)
except Exception:
    data = None
```

Also, writing `if data:` [would be better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9494404/use-of-true-false-and-none-as-return-values-in-python-functions) than `if data is True:`.

Comment: both proposed solution worked fine .

Comment: That's great! Although you don't need both at the same time. In my opinion, @Blckknght's answer is better, since it avoids the use of exceptions, thus making the code faster (I'm the one who has upvoted it).  I wrote my answer to just add another way of doing this.