# Why does (not None) == True evaluate to True?

Tags: python, python-2.7

This tripped me up recently in a piece of Python code - I was checking if any of the values in a list were False, so I used something like:

```
if any(not v for v in values):
    # Do something...
```

However, I forgot that there were `None` values in the list, so I kept getting confusing outputs until I remembered to check for that first. That got me wondering though - what's the rationale behind `(not None) == True`? `None == False` evaluates to `False`, so it's not reflexive, and it's not immediately clear to me why the logical negation of the `None` object should evaluate to `True`.

Comment: `(not None) == True` produces `True`.

Comment: Whoops, that's what I meant - sorry!

Comment: `not` is an operator that produces a boolean value, the inverse of the *truth value* of it's operand. I suspect you are confusing the truth value with the boolean value. The latter is only `True` or `False`, truth value can be *converted* to a boolean value by passing it to the `bool()` function.

Comment: Since `None` is a falsy value, it seems logical that `not None` is a truthy value. What is it that confuses you exactly?

Comment: Side note: using a list comprehension inside `any()` or `all()` completely defeats the purpose of those functions. Use a generator expression, always.

Comment: @VincentSavard: `not None` is not only a truthy value. It is a *boolean* value. `None` itself, however, is not  a boolean value.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Indeed. I'm just explaining the thought process you can infer from knowing that `None` is a falsy value. After all, `True` _is_ a truthy value. :)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I've never head of *truth values* - I assumed they were the same as boolean values. That answers my question - please add that as an answer and I'll mark it as such.

Comment: @VincentSavard - the confusion comes from the delineation between a truth value and a boolean value. I guess it makes sense that `None` is a falsy value - it represents a lack of something - it just wasn't an immediately obvious conclusion to me. My follow-up question then is why does `int(1) == True` but `int(5) != True`? Neither is `None`, both seem truthy from a C programmer's POV.

Comment: @tonysdg I don't have time to write a detailed answer right now, but in short. there's a slight difference (which is at the source of your confusion) between `not None == True` and `5 == True`: In one case, you're comparing `True` to a `bool` while in the other, to an `int`. If you do `bool(5) == True`, you'll notice it is `True`.

Comment: @tonysdg this is just like C, if `True` is defined as `1`. `int(5) != True`, but `if int(5):` will execute the following block.

Comment: @VincentSavard - I'll take that - I'm guessing part of my confusion comes from the fact that I primarily work in C, not python, so I'm trying to apply apples to oranges. Thank you for your time!

Comment: @tonysdg: for historical reasons, `True == 1` and `False == 0`. That's because Python did not always have a `bool` type; in the good old days we used `0` and `1` instead. For the same reason, `issubclass(bool, int)` is also true, booleans are a special type of integer. See [Is False == 0 and True == 1 in Python an implementation detail or is it guaranteed by the language?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2764017)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`not` is an operator that produces a *boolean* value, the inverse of the [*truth value*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) of it's operand.

I suspect you are confusing the truth value with the boolean value. The latter is only either `True` or `False`, but the truth value of any Python object can be *converted* to a boolean value by passing it to the `bool()` function. Statements like `if` and `while`, operators like `and`, `or` and `not` test for truth values, not specifically boolean values. `any()` and `all()` test each value in the iterable for truth as well.

As such, you should never need to do `if some_expression == True` or `if not some_expression == True` when testing truth values. Just use `if some_expression` or `if not some_expression`.

Note that `not` *has* to return a boolean value because you can't, usually, invert a truth value. What would the inverse be of `0` or an empty list, for example? `0` is considered false, but *any other integer* would be considered true, so what value would `not 0` return if not `False`? For lists, what would you put in the list to produce `not []`?

Answer (score 0):

The explanation for why it happens is in the comments to your question. A good way to check if anything within your list evaluates to false is:

```
if not all(values):
```

There are many ways to do what you're doing but this for me is more readable than the list comprehension you have.

Answer (score 0):

This answer to a related question contains some good info you may want to check out, explaining detail about the use of `True`, `False`, and `None` in Python: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9494887/4174975

An explanation that's perhaps more specific to your answer can be found in the O'Reilly book *Introducing Python* by Bill Lubanovic, who refers to Python programs that use the concept of "truthiness" and "falsiness" to check for empty data structures as well as `False` conditions. The author even has a subsection on page 88 titled "None is Useful" which elaborates:

> `None` is a special Python value that holds a place when there is nothing to say.
>   It is not the same as the boolean value `False`, although it looks false when evaluated as boolean.
>   [...]
>   You'll need `None` to distinguish a missing value from an empty value... zero-valued integers or floats, empty string (''), lists([]), tuples((,)), dictionaries({}), and sets(set()) are all `False`, but are not equal to `None`.

So that is the rationale behind *why* `None` behaves the way that it does, and has subtle qualities apart from what you get with `True` and `False` or a `1` or a `0`.

As to the other part of your question, it appears to be a logical tautology: `None` is `False` because Python interprets the `None` as being the equivalent of a `null` for the reasons found above. By adding `not` to a `None`, you are inverting its boolean value, which turns it into a `True`.