# How to return a bool and a string in a return statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, boolean

I have the following statement:

```
if Game.item_can_move(item_target) == True:
    return True + ""

else:
    return False + ", error"
```

but this doesn't seem to work. I would like to return a bool, str in both of the return.

Comment: Use  , instead of +

Comment: ok let me try using a comma instead

Comment: return a tuple: `return (False, "")`  - the () are optional, the `,` is important part

Comment: Consider raising an exception in the invalid case, rather than having the calling code check return values.

Comment: BTW, [don't do `if boolean == True`, just do `if boolean`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9494887/4518341)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use three strategies here,

1. **Use <del>Object</del> Class**

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self): 
        self.foo = "foo"
        self.is_bar = True   
    
def my_method(): 
    return Foo() 
          
tmp = my_method()  
print(tmp.foo) 
print(tmp.is_bar)
```

2. **Use Tuple**

```
def my_method(): 
    foo = "foo"
    is_bar = True
    return foo, is_bar
```

3. **Use a list/dic/..**

```
def my_method(): 
    foo = "foo"
    is_bar = True
    return [foo, is_bar]
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354883/how-do-i-return-multiple-values-from-a-function)

Comment: All of those are objects, just to be clear

Answer (score 0):

You can return multiple things at once with commas:

```
if Game.item_can_move(item_target) == True:
    return True, ""

else:
    return False, "error"
```

The reason your code didn't work is because you cannot concat a python `str` with a `bool` type. You *can*, however, do:

```
if Game.item_can_move(item_target) == True:
    return str(True) + ", "

else:
    return str(False) + ", error"
```

---

BTW, your code can be simplified:

```
b = Game.item_can_move(item_target)
if b:
    return b, ""
return b, "error"
```

Comment: Further simplified: `return b, ("" if b else "error")`

Comment: Can be further simplified by removing `else` and going directly to the `return` statement

Comment: @jdaz How, taking into account the different strings that need to be returned?

Comment: To be clear, keep `return b, "error"`, but just take it out of the `else` block. If `b`, then it returns `b, ""` and the function ends. Then the only way it can get to the next line of `return b, "error"` is if `b` is falsey. So you don’t need `else`.