# How to check if exactly one of two condition is met

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am checking wether one of two conditions applies and only one.

My question is if there is a way to have a single if statement to do this:

```
if x == True:
    if y == False:
        do_something()
elif x == False:
    if y == True:
        do_something()
```

Ideally similar to how `and` and `or` work so that it would something like:

```
enter code here
if x == True ° y == True:
    do_something()
```

whereas `°` is the wanted operator

- do nothing if: x,y = True or x,y = False
- do something if: x = True and y = False or x = False and y = True

I would appreciate any advice if this is not possible.

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: because you are checking for x and y, you want to make sure x and y are not the same. The only way it is true is if x != y. So check for it and you have your answer

Comment: Sidenote, comparing against booleans is generally bad practice. See [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations:~:text=Don't%20compare%20boolean%20values%20to%20True%20or%20False%20using%20%3D%3D%3A) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9494887/4518341). Instead of `if x == True` and `if x == False`, simply use `if x` and `if not x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the logical operator `XOR`, but in this scenario, it's the equivalent of just saying

```
if x != y: 
   do_something()
```

As it will only be true if one of the conditions is met.

-- update --

There's also an actual `XOR` operator

```
if x ^ y:
   do_something()
```

They will be identical in this example.