# Is there only one True and one False object in Python?

Tags: python, object, boolean, instance

I know that Python guarantees that there is only one instance of `NoneType`, the `None` object, so that you can safely use `is None` to test if something equals `None`.

Is there an equivalent guarantee for `bool` `True` and `False` (i.e. that there is only one instance of each)?

If not, why not?

**EDIT:** In particular, I've noticed that `(n+0) is (0+n)` gives `True` for n in `range(-5, 257)` and `False` otherwise. In other words, zero, the first 256 positive and the first 5 negative integers seem to be pre-cached and are not instanced again. I am guessing that that's a choice of the interpreter (CPython, in my case) and not a specification of the language. And `bool` derives from `int`, so I still have to wonder about what expectations I can have with other interpreters.

**EDIT:** To clarify, since this seems to have generated a lot of confusion, my intention is *not* to test the boolean interpretation of a value. For that I would never use `is True` or `is False`. My intention is to be able to tell apart `False` from everything else, in a variable that can have values of several types including empty strings, zeros, and `None`, and similarly for `True`. I'm myself an experienced programmer, of the kind who cringes when I see "if booleanvar == True".

**NOTE ON DUPLICATES:** The questions this one was alleged to be a duplicate of ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764017/is-false-0-and-true-1-in-python-an-implementation-detail-or-is-it-guarante) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764017/is-false-0-and-true-1-in-python-an-implementation-detail-or-is-it-guarante)) don't answer this question; they merely state that `bool` is a subclass of `int` that differ mainly in their `repr`, not if `True` and `False` are guaranteed to be unique.

Also, note that it's not a question about what the *names* `True` and `False` are bound to, but about the *instances* of the class `bool`.

Comment: Why would you need/want to do this?  Something like `if var is True:` is ugly compared to just `if var:`.

Comment: Generally speaking: Don't test against `True` or `False`. Use the implicit boolean values of expressions instead.

Comment: 1. It depends which version of Python; and 2. Never rely on this (per [PEP-0008](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations): *"Yes: `if greeting:`, No: `if greeting == True:`, Worse: `if greeting is True:`*).

Comment: PEP-0008 applies to values known to be boolean. I want to use it to test for type and value at the same time. My question is if there's a guarantee that these objects are unique; I'm not looking for advice on the usage.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: The linked question claimed as "duplicate" does not answer this. I'm not asking what the True and False names are bound to; I'm asking if the object instances that True and False are initially bound to are guaranteed to be unique. I know that there can be multiple instances of the string 'x', for example, all with the same value, and thus the `is` operator may fail. I'll edit the question to remove True and False from the tests.

Comment: @PedroGimeno: that question *very much* answers that. In Python 2, no, they are not guaranteed to be unique because you can rebind the names. In Python 3, they are unique values.

Comment: @PedroGimeno: I strongly urge you not to use `is True` or `is False` however. You'd use `if something:` instead, and **not** test against True or False. If you have to have a boolean, at best use `isinstance(object, bool)`.

Comment: The *built-in* names `True` and `False` are singletons, however.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the docs (https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy):

> Booleans
>
> These represent the truth values False and True. The two objects representing the values False and True are the only Boolean objects.

There are only two objects, any computation producing a boolean will produce one of those two existing objects:

```
>>> (1 == 1) is True
True
>>> (1 == 0) is False
True
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly the answer I was looking for, with support from a normative source.

Answer (score 1):

The `bool` type has only two instances, `True` and `False`. Furthermore, it can't be subclassed, so there's no way to create a derived class that can have additional instances.

But even though it's guaranteed, there's seldom a good reason to rely upon it. You should usually use `if x` rather than `if x is True`, and avoid situations where you need to distinguish `True` from other truthy values or `False` from other falsy values.

Comment: But sometimes you generate an instance by performing calculations; e.g. `(917+543) is (916+544)` gives `False`. So do I have a guarantee that if I produce False or True, I won't have a new instance? It's not clear from your answer.

Comment: @PedroGimeno you're comparing two ints and asking if they are the same references. Nothing to do with booleans in your question. If you call bool on those ints though, you get the result you expect. ```>>> bool(917+543) is bool(916+544)```
```True```

Comment: @JoshSmeaton: My question is about instances. With `is`, I'm asking if they are the same instance. I used the `int` example because `bool` is a subclass of `int`. Please see the recent edit to my question.