# Python if statement not recognized though conditions appear to be met

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm trying to add 1 to the count each time there's a new letter and keep track of the doubled letters, but python isn't going into the if statement, despite line 6 showing the conditions for the if statement are met. What am I missing?

```
def duplicate_count(text):
    count = 0
    doubled_letters = []
    for i in text:
        print (i)
        print(i in doubled_letters)
        if i in doubled_letters == False:
            count += 1
            doubled_letters.append(i)
    print(count)
    print(doubled_letters)
    return count

duplicate_count("abbcdea")
```

this returns:

```
a
False
b
False
b
False
c
False
d
False
e
False
a
False
0
[]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`in` is a comparison operator, so it [gets chained](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) with `==`. Your expression is equivalent to

```
(i in doubled_letters) and (double_letters == False)
```

You could "break the chain", so to speak, using explicit parentheses:

```
if (i in double_letters) == False:
```

but direct comparisons to Boolean literals are rarely, if ever, necessary. Just write

```
if i not in double_letters:
```

(Note that `not in` is a single, two-word operator, not an application of `not` to `in`. The equivalent with `in` would be `not (i in double_letters)`.)

Comment: even if you need to use literals, `is True` is preferred over `== True`

Comment: Both are pretty terrible; I wouldn't bother trying to choose a preference.

Comment: @AnkurS `is True` tests for identity, so it may not yield the same results as ` == True`. I don't know where you've seen that it would be "preferred", as far as I'm concerned such a test would not pass a code review.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers See https://stackoverflow.com/a/24846681/1126841; `True` and `False` are guaranteed unique, like `None`, so it would at least be safe, if still unnecessary, to use `is`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your logic is also flawed in addition to the incorrect usage of the operator. Looks like you are trying to get a count of duplicated letters, but I don't think your program will be able to do it.

I guess you are expecting something like this:

```
def duplicate_count(text):
    count = 0
    letters = []
    for i in text:
        if i not in doubled_letters:
            letters.append(i)
        else:
            count += 1

    print(count)
    return count

duplicate_count("abbcdea")
```

In the above code, I am trying to add every letter to a list and if they are duplicated, I increase the count. Based on this, you should be getting 2 as `a` and `b` are duplicated in the input.

Comment: thanks, that's what my program is meant to do, but when I kept getting this error I took out all of the stuff that wasn't causing a problem so I could focus in on the important part to post here. The code above is just the problematic fragment.