# When is it ok to check for literal values with "is" in Python?

Tags: python

I want to check if a variable is `True` (not just its truthiness).

This is easily checked like this:

```py
>>> a = 1
>>> isinstance(a, bool) and a
False

>>> a = True
>>> isinstance(a, bool) and a
True
```

Of course, that is totally fine. However, the same behaviour can be seen in the following code:

```py
>>> a = 1
>>> a is True
False

>>> a = True
>>> a is True
True
```

In my opinion, the second snippet is a bit more readable (if you understand how `is` works). With Python 3.8, I get a `SyntaxWarning` when executing the second snippet. Would the second example work with all Python implementations? Is there a guarantee that `bool` objects of the same value are identical in this way? I believe I have read somewhere that this is not guaranteed for `int` objects. Is it ever ok to check literal values with `is` like this?

Comment: Short answer: When you want an equality check, _do an equality check_, not an identity check. Behaviors which are present as optimizations are not guaranteed; and it's only safe to rely on a language feature (in a future-proofing / alternate-implementation-compatibility sense of "safe") where that feature is actually part of the documented spec.

Comment: What exactly does the `SyntaxWarning ` say?

Comment: "With Python 3.8, I get a SyntaxWarning when executing the second snippet." I do not. Please post the exact error message.

Comment: Partial duplicate: [Is there only one True and one False object in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24842852/4518341)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! @wjandrea the answers from your link did answer my question. According to PEP 285, `True` and `False` are indeed singletons and so `x is True` is guaranteed to be equivalent to `isinstance(x, bool) and x`.

Comment: The `SyntaxWarning` says `SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?`