# Why is "is None" ok, but "is True" is not?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know that this question has been asked a bunch of times (for this I apologize), and [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) "covers" it by saying that `if x is True` << `x == True` << `if x`, but I still don't understand *why*. It is my understanding that both `None` and `True` are singletons in Python, so I don't quite see the nuance. This especially confuses me because PEP8 says:

> Comparisons to singletons like None should always be done with is or
> is not, never the equality operators.

I also understand that the `if x` syntax covers a few more cases than `if x is True` in that `if x` can do things like check for a non-empty string/list/etc or a non-zero number, but in the case where you know `x` is a boolean value, why is it so incorrect to compare with `is`?

Is the reason that PEP8 assumes that `if x` is safer because it covers the case that `if x is True` covers *and* those other cases I referenced above?

Comment: `True` and `False` are _literals_

Comment: `None` is guaranteed to be a singleton by the language definition. `True` is a singleton only by the optimization of the CPython interpreter.

Comment: It's not necessarily *incorrect* to use `x is True`. In some specific cases it's *correct*, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27276610/boolean-identity-true-vs-is-true

Comment: @KlausD. [citation needed] :-)

Comment: More specifically, your question is closer to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050335/strange-pep8-recommendation-on-comparing-boolean-values-to-true-or-false

Comment: I won't be surprised if the root of this goes back to Python 2 (and perhaps 1...), where one could easily override the values of `True` and `False`: `orig_true = True ; orig_false = False ; True = 1 ; False = 0 ; print orig_true == True ; print orig_true is True` This beauty outputs `True, False`

Comment: This answer quotes a key information from the docs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24846681/5378816 . If `True` and `False` are the only two boolean objects, they must be singletons. Otherwise a third boolean object could be created.

Comment: @KellyBundy Wrong website!

Comment: @KlausD. More like wrong claim (your original comment).

Comment: Ahhhh @KlausD. that was the missing piece of info for me. Thank you for that, that's super helpful!