# Python conditional one or the other but not both

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am trying to compile an if statement in python where it checks two variables to see if they are <= .05. Now if both variables are True, I just want the code to pass/continue, but if only one of the variables are True, then I want the code to do something. eg:

```
ht1 = 0.04
ht2 = 0.03

if (ht1 <= 0.05) or (ht2 <= 0.05):
    # do something
else:
    pass
```

I don't think this example will work the way I would want it as my understanding of OR is 1 condition returns True or both conditions return True. If someone could assit in pointing me in the right direction, it would greatly be apprecaited.

Comment: you can think of xor operation something like this ,   if bool((ht1 <= 0.05)) != bool((ht2 <= 0.05)):

Comment: Related: [How do you get the logical xor of two variables in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/432842/3357935)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What you want is called an "exclusive-OR", which in this case can be expressed as a 'not-equal' or 'is not' relation:

```
if (ht <= 0.05) is not (ht2 <= 0.05):
```

The way this works is that the `if` will only succeed if one of them is `True` and the other one is `False`. If they're both `True` or both `False` then it'll go to the `else` block.

Comment: Correct, but subtle. Relational expressions return a bool. A bool is one or other  of the two singleton objects `True` or `False`. Therefore, `is not` is an appropriate test. Personally I'd prefer `!=`.

Comment: @nigel222 Agree that it's a little subtle; I only used `is not` specifically due to the fact that it's a comparison of `bool`s. It reads a little cleaner to me this way, but that's definitely a taste thing. In my mind, the `!=` would get a little lost among the other `<=` comparisons even though it's serving a vastly different purpose (i.e. might seem mathematical even though it's a logical operator).

Comment: Thanks for that explanation. To me, the brackets in `(ht1 <= 0.05) != (ht2 <= 0.05)` make the `!=` stand apart. Agreed, taste not substance.

Comment: I find the behavior of `if (ht <= 0.05) ^ (ht2 <= 0.05):` more obvious for some reason. Someone used to exclusive-or `^` will immediately see that this condition is only true when exactly one of the members is true.

Answer (score 9):

Since relational operators always result in a `bool`, just check to see if they are different values.

```
if (ht1 <= 0.05) != (ht2 <= 0.05): # Check if only one is true
   ...
```

Answer (score 3):

This method is technically slower because it has to calculate the comparisons twice, but I find it slightly more readable. Your mileage may vary.

```
ht1 = 0.04
ht2 = 0.03

if (ht1 <= 0.05) and (ht2 <= 0.05):
   pass
elif (ht1 <= 0.05) or (ht2 <= 0.05):
    # do something.
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another way of doing so:

```
if  max(ht1, ht2) > 0.05 and min(ht1, ht2) <= 0.05:
```