# Understanding Logical Statements

Tags: python, boolean

I had this question on a recent test:

> There are two wolves, a and b, and the parameters a_howl and b_howl
>   indicate if each is howling. We are in trouble if they are both
>   howling or if neither of them is howling. Return True if we are in
>   trouble.
>
> wolf_trouble(True, True) → True
>
> wolf_trouble(False, False) → True
>
> wolf_trouble(True, False) → False

My code was as below, and prior to submitting I tested that it worked on all three conditions.

```
def wolf_trouble(a_howl, b_howl):
    if a_howl == True & b_howl == True:
        return True
    elif a_howl == False & b_howl == False:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

There was an additional test condition that wasn't mentioned however, and due to this, I only got partial credit. :

> wolf_trouble(False, True) → False

wolf_trouble(False, True) returns True when I run my code, and I'm trying to understand why. Since I have set all conditions that aren't (True, True) or (False, False) to return False, why am I seeing this result?

Apart from hard coding every possible permutation, what steps can I take so that my code does take care of these conditions?

Comment: Note: `&` is a bitwise operator in Python. You should use `and`.

Comment: Very very *very* related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432842/how-do-you-get-the-logical-xor-of-two-variables-in-python

Comment: If a_howl and b_howl are equal, we're in trouble.  Otherwise we're not.  So: `return a_howl == b_howl`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`&` is **the bitwise and operator**. Instead you should have used `and`, which is **the logical and operator**. Note, BTW you could have simplified this function considerably by simply checking if `a_howl` and `b_howl` are equal:

```
def wolf_trouble(a_howl, b_howl):
    return a_howl == b_howl
```

Comment: Thank you! I think I acquired the habit of using "&" from having to use it within the Pandas library.