# python conditional statement unreasonble results

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I try to understand why I get unreasonable result from the following `if`:

```
def print_if_neg (a,b):   
    if a < 0 != b < 0:
        print "Only One Neg"
    else:
        print "0 or 2"

print_if_neg(1,1)
print_if_neg(-1,1)
print_if_neg (1,-1)
print_if_neg(-1,-1)
```

I get 3 times `0 or 2` and then last one `Only One Neg`.
What is the order of this complicated condition?

I've tried this:

```
if (a < 0) != (b < 0):
```

and it's ok but I'm trying to understand why above doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because condition `a < 0 != b < 0` means `a < 0` AND `0 != b` AND `b < 0` First of all when `a >= 0` first condition evaluates to False and so nothing else gets evaluated. Then, if a is <0 but b=1 last condition in the chain is False. Therefore your chained condition is False 3 out of 4 times.

This is well explained in [section 6.10](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) of Python documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You need parentheses due to [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)

```
def print_if_neg (a,b):   
    if (a < 0) != (b < 0):
        print "Only One Neg"
    else:
        print "0 or 2"
```

Answer (score 1):

As CoryKramer pointed out, the operator precedence is making the difference.

Your code is equivalent to this:

```
def print_if_neg (a,b):   
    if a < (0 != b) < 0:
        print "Only One Neg"
    else:
        print "0 or 2"
```

Because `!=` has higher precedence than `<` by language definition.

So, use `()` to force the precedence that you need:

```
def print_if_neg (a,b):   
    if (a < 0) != (b < 0):
        print "Only One Neg"
    else:
        print "0 or 2"
```

Also, FYI you are coding the [`xor` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/433161/1094246).

Answer (score 1):

Due to operator precedence you need to place the two conditions in parentheses for your expected results. Otherwise the comparison operators are solved, checking for `0 != b` in your code, which is not what you expect.

```
def print_if_neg (a,b):
    if (a < 0) != (b < 0):
        print ("Only One Neg")
    else:
        print ("0 or 2")

print_if_neg(1,1)
print_if_neg(-1,1)
print_if_neg (1,-1)
print_if_neg(-1,-1)
```

Note that all comparison operators have the same precedence and comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., `x < y <= z` is equivalent to `x < y` AND `y <= z`

Answer (score 0):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11036506/5069105), you could make it more readable imo:

```
from operator import xor
def print_if_neg (a, b):   
    if xor(a < 0, b < 0):
        print "Only One Neg"
    else:
        print "0 or 2"
```