# Python validation from if neither inputs equal a number

Tags: python, validation, printing, while-loop

I am having an issue with Python validation.  I was wondering if there was a simple way to put validation on two input numbers to check a few things:
If the inputs are ints
if neither of the inputs equals a certain number, they are not valid.  (For example, this would mean one of them would have to be 5.  So `a = 1` `b = 4`, `a = 3` `b = 2`, `a = 1` `b = 1` wouldn't work)
If the two numbers are the same number that is required it will not work (E.G. if a = 5 b = 5 will not work as 5 is the required number, however a = 1 b = 5 would work as 5 is only being inputted once).

```
while True:
    a = input("Enter first input: ")
    b = input("Enter second input: ")
    try:
        val = int(a)
        val1 = int(a)
        if val1 != 5 or val != 5:
            print("I'm sorry but it must be a pos int and equal 5")
            continue
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("That's not an int")
```

This is what I was trying to do, but I think I may be dreadfully wrong?
Any help appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: can you explain it a bit better? the code does not match what you are stating

Comment: You assign both `val` and `val1` to `int(a)`. One should be `int(b)`

Comment: Why do you **think** it is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Logical xor

You should continue the loop if exactly one `a` and `b` is equal to 5. It means you need a logical [`xor`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432842/how-do-you-get-the-logical-xor-of-two-variables-in-python). Parens are needed to avoid comparing `a` to `5 ^ b`:

```
while True:
    a = input("Enter first input: ")
    b = input("Enter second input: ")
    try:
        a = int(a)
        b = int(b)
        if (a != 5) ^ (b != 5):
            print("I'm sorry but it must be a pos int and equal 5")
            continue
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("That's not an int")
```

It might not be very readable though.

## Count 5's

You could count the number of ints equal to 5:

```
while True:
    a = input("Enter first input: ")
    b = input("Enter second input: ")
    try:
        a = int(a)
        b = int(b)
        count5 = [a, b].count(5)
        if count5 == 1:
            break
        else:
            print("Exactly one input should be equal to 5.")
    except ValueError:
        print("That's not an int")
```

If you want to differentiate between errors:

```
while True:
    a = input("Enter first input: ")
    b = input("Enter second input: ")
    try:
        a = int(a)
        b = int(b)
        count5 = [a, b].count(5)
        if count5 == 2:
            print("Inputs cannot both be equal to 5.")
        elif count5 == 0:
            print("At least one input should be equal to 5.")
        else:
            break
    except ValueError:
        print("That's not an int")
```

Here's an example:

```
Enter first input: 3
Enter second input: 1
At least one input should be equal to 5.
Enter first input: 5
Enter second input: 5
Inputs cannot both be equal to 5.
Enter first input: 3
Enter second input: 5
```

Comment: @JohnSmith: Thanks for the comment. Updated.

Comment: @abercrombiefan1 in this case you should accept his answer

Answer (score 0):

Logic... if True then break, False then print error message...

Two things... you want logical exclusive or so that True ^ True = False
You aren't storing b.  The text you're printing doesn't explain what's happening.

```
  while True:
    a = input("Enter first input: ")
    b = input("Enter second input: ")
    try:
        a = int(a)  # like the readable code using a not val1... 
        b = int(b)
        if (a != 5) ^ (b != 5):  # added parens as suggested
            break
        else:
            print("I'm sorry but it must be a pos int and equal 5")
            continue
    except ValueError:
        print("That's not an int")
```

Output

```
Enter first input: 5

Enter second input: 5
I'm sorry but it must be a pos int and equal 5

Enter first input: 1

Enter second input: 5

runfile('...')

Enter first input: 5

Enter second input: 5
I'm sorry but it must be a pos int and equal 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
(a == 5 and b != 5) or (a != 5 and b == 5)
```

Or this:

```
(a == 5) != (b == 5)
```

(`!=` is the boolean equivalent of bitwise xor)