# Python checking if exactly one object is not None

Tags: python

I have two python objects `a` and `b`.

What is the best/most-efficient/most-pythonic way to check if exactly one of these objects is `None`?

Comment: You seem to be asking 3 different questions. Do you want the best, the most efficient, or the most Pythonic? The first and third are opinions, so off-topic. The 2nd is probably not important: [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)

Comment: `if not` perhaps?

Comment: `sum(x is None for x in (a,b)) == 1` that sounds overkill, though :)

Comment: `(a is None) != (b is None)`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre that trades on the booleans in Python being numbers, and I know they are, but it still bugs me that we leverage it. It makes me feel dirty in a type-violation sort of way.

Comment: booleans are integers. `True == 1`, `False == 0`. that's written in stone

Answer (score 10):

Use Python's `^` (XOR) operator.

```
(a is None) ^ (b is None)
```

Comment: I am torn as to whether or not it is preferable to use `!=`. Yes, logical and bitwise XOR are equivalent for booleans, but still...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm torn too. When I think "exactly one of two booleans is True" I automatically think XOR, but `!=` fits just as well.

Comment: This is why I referenced the older question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432842/how-do-you-get-the-logical-xor-of-two-variables-in-python

Comment: Yes, for me the problem is the distinction between bitwise and logical operators. Unfortunately, python doesn't have a logical exclusive-or operator. When I glance at the code and see the bitwise `^`, I think "there's some bitwise operation going on here", but on the other hand, `!=` isn't immediatebly "XOR" in my head.

Comment: I did a quick benchmark and ^ seems to be marginally more efficient.

Answer (score 5):

What you effectively want is the XOR or Exclusive OR function on whether those two objects are None. The following should work for you:

`(a is None) ^ (b is None)`

A more exhaustive answer on how to get XOR on objects in Python can be found here:

[How do you get the logical xor of two variables in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432842/how-do-you-get-the-logical-xor-of-two-variables-in-python)