# Best way to ensure user to specify one and only one of the two function parameters in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, parameter-passing

In `some_function`, I have two parameters `freq` and `frac`, I don't want users to specify both of them, or none of them. I want them to specify just one of them.

Here is the working code:

```
def some_function(freq=False, frac=False):
    if (freq is False) & (frac is False):
        return (str(ValueError)+': Both freq and frac are not specified')
    elif (freq is not False) & (frac is not False):
        return (str(ValueError)+': Both freq and frac are specified')
    elif (freq is not False) & (frac is False):
        try:
            print ('Do something')
        except Exception as e:
            print (e)
    elif (freq is False) & (frac is not False):
        try: 
            print ('Do something else')
        except Exception as e:
            print (e)
    else: return (str(ValueError)+': Undetermined error')
```

Are there better and less verbose practices to express this in Python?

Comment: Python [needs a logical xor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/432842/2564301) ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `assert` before your `if` statement. The type of your inputs is unclear; in general, I would use `None` if I know this isn't a valid input.

```
def some_function(freq=None, frac=None):

    freq_flag = freq is not None
    frac_flag = frac is not None

    assert freq_flag + frac_flag == 1, "Specify exactly one of freq or frac"

    if freq_flag:
        print('Do something')

    elif frac_flag:
        print('Do something else')
```

Comment: Doesn't save many lines, but makes a lot more readable coding. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot you're doing wrong here.  You can test `not frac` instead of `frac is False`, you should be using logical `and` instead of bitwise `&`, and you should be raising those `ValueError`s, not returning them:

```
def some_function(freq=False, frac=False):
    if not freq and not frac:
        raise ValueError('Both freq and frac are not specified')
    elif freq and frac:
       raise ValueError('Both freq and frac are specified')
    elif freq:      
        print ('Do something')
    else:
        print ('Do something else')
```

Generally though, you're looking for one of two options.  Why not require that the user pass a single boolean, then represents `freq` if `True` and `frac` if `False`?

```
def some_function(freq):
    if freq: 
        print ('Do something')
    else:
        print ('Do something else')
```

Comment: If the same argument doubles for `freq` OR `fraq`, you still need an argument `flag` to indicate whether that first argument is `freq` or `fraq`. I think the use case is not with Booleans but with an actual value (number, string, or list) instead, for only one of the two.

Comment: True, the real user case is to have None or actual float value. But thanks very much for pointing out my errors in coding (never cease to learn the nuances).

Answer (score 0):

Dead simple pythonic solution: use two distinct functions (they can eventually just be facades for the real one):

```
__all__ = ["freqfunc", "fracfunc"]

# private implementation
def _somefunc(freq=False, frac=False):
   # your code here

def freqfunc(freq):
    return _somefunc(freq=freq)

def fraqfunc(frac):
    return _somefunc(frac=frac)
```

Now there might be better solutions but it's impossible to tell without more details...