# Given two non-zero integers, print "YES" if exactly one of them is positive and print "NO" otherwise (Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7

First time asking a question on stackoverflow. I am stuck trying to solve this. This is my code:

```
a = int(input()) 
b = int(input())
```

Given two non-zero integers, print "YES" if exactly one of them is positive and print "NO" otherwise.

```
if (a > 0) or (b > 0):
    print('YES') 
else:
    print('NO')
```

Comment: `(a>0) != (b>0)`

Comment: @Blacksilver That comment, expanded a little, would make a better answer than the other answers on this question.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (a>0) != (b>0):
    print("YES")
else:
    print("NO")
```

[How do you get the logical xor of two variables in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432842/how-do-you-get-the-logical-xor-of-two-variables-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with more complex Boolean operations, but having multiple conditions is the simplest way:

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())

if (a > 0 and b < 0) or (a < 0 and b > 0):
    print('YES')
else:
    print('NO')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print('YES' if a * b < 0 else 'NO')
```

Comment: This would print Yes is they were both negative unfortunately.

Comment: my python interpreter says no. i tested it with pythonista and a=-1  b=-2

Answer (score 1):

Tomothy32's answer is the best approach for sure as-goes simplicity and more importantly, understandability. But here's another way of doing the same thing, just to illustrate how another programmer might do this:

```
onePositive = ( (a > 0 and b < 0) or (a < 0 and b > 0) )

print('yes' if onePositive else 'no' )
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the fastest solution or 1-liner but will help you understand my thought process in solving the problem given exactly 2 non zero integers, print yes if exactly one of them is positive and no otherwise.

Solution - you want EXACTLY ONE POSITIVE MEANING THE OTHER ONE MUST BE NEGATIVE if both integers are NON-ZERO

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())

#if a is positive and b and negative
if (a > 0) and (b < 0) :
    print('YES')
#if a is negative and b is positive
elif (a < 0) and (b > 0) :
    print('YES')
else :
    print('NO')
```