# Python check for either parameters but not both

Tags: python

I have a python3 script running a FlaskAPI, I require either parameterA or parameterB but not both.

```
parameterA = request.form.get('parameterA')
parameterB = request.form.get('parameterB')

if (parameterA is None) or (parameterA == '') :
    print('Parameter A is missing')
```

I can check for Parameter A but how do I modify this so that it checks for either parameterA or parameterB but errors on both?

Comment: xor you mean? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432842/how-do-you-get-the-logical-xor-of-two-variables-in-python

Comment: `if parameterA and parameterB: raise Exception`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define an initial value when using `get` on `dict`. Using this feature you can remove checking for `None` because if the value is not present in the `request.form` it will initiate it with the empty string ().

After that you can check for either of the variables like below:

```py
parameterA = request.form.get('parameterA','')
parameterB = request.form.get('parameterB','')

#if both of them are '' then you don't have any of them and it raises error
#if none of them are '' then you have both of them and it raises error
if (parameterA == '' and parameterB == '') or (parameterA != '' and parameterB != '') :
    print('Parameter A and B are not suitable')
```

Another fun way:

```
if ['',''] == [parameterA, parameterB] or not ('' in [parameterA, parameterB]) :
    print('Parameter A and B are not suitable')
```

First one checks for both empty value and the second one checks for the both passed.

Comment: But what if both of them have values, I want it to error under those circumstances as well

Comment: Got it .I just completed it with your desired one. Check it