# How to verify function doing xor in python with n arguments and coercion?

Tags: python, xor, coercion

New to python. How do I verify a function implementing an n parameters xor when using the `^` operator? I extended the code to handle string input. To do so, I made the assumption that `0.0`, `''` and `None` would be `0`, and any other value, positive or negative, would be `1`. However, integer values would be handled in the usual way, so that `6^5 == 3`. I'd prefer to coerce the input to integer where it can be coerced (e.g. `11.0` or `'11'` could be cast as `int`).

I've seen the issue of logical versus bitwise xor operations in python covered elsewhere, but their limitations are that the discussions are limited to inputs `a` and `b` only. I would like to verify a solution tested to an arbitrary number of arguments and coerced inputs.

### Other solutions checked

I experimented with a few suggestions for logical xor from [How do you get the logical xor of two variables in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432842/how-do-you-get-the-logical-xor-of-two-variables-in-python). However, none of the solutions that I tried seemed to work. For example:

- `^` doesn't work with strings, and isn't iterable.
- `int(bool(a) ^ bool(b))` doesn't work with `n` arguments.
- `(a and not b) or (not a and b)` breaks if the input `b` is a string.

### What I tried

I started with the following code.

#### Exhibit 1

```py
def xor(*args):
    return int(any(args) != all(args))
```

*Exhibit 1* has logic that only works for the case of two arguments, and I haven't figured out what it's truth table resembles in the case of more arguments. As a result, I tweaked the function to use the `^=` operator, as follows.

#### Exhibit 2

```py
def xor(*args, parity = True):
    exOr = False
    checker = list()
    for arg in args:
        # try to coerce arg to int, so that '11' = 11, 11.0 = 11
        exOr ^= arg if type(arg) == int else bool(arg)
        checker.append(bool(arg))
    exOr = 0 if all(checker) and not parity else exOr
    return int(exOr)
```

The logic for *Exhibit 2* seems to work for any number of arguments I have tested, albeit writing down a truth table manually on paper and following along in python output is prone to error. Also, the code in *Exhibit 2* doesn't coerce inputs at all where they can be coerced.

#### Why the parity parameter in Exhibit 2?

There seems to be some disagreement over two interpretations of xor logic for more than two inputs ([xor - The Interesting Gate](https://mindhunter74.wordpress.com/2011/04/25/xor-the-interesting-gate/) and [How is an xor with more than two inputs supposed to work](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/93713/how-is-an-xor-with-more-than-2-inputs-supposed-to-work/160690#160690?newreg=9ab285aac8b048f79733bc704a39331a)). It seems to me that a solution for more than two inputs should select between both options, since both are written into standards apparently, which is why I added the accumulator and the logic to invert `all(checker)`.

## Summary of Questions

I hope the above discussion makes sense. I don't know how to test the code efficiently, and I don't know how to coerce the input to `int` if it can be. For testing the code I feel like I need a better method than comparing paper notes with function output.

Answer (score 0):

This post regards a solution to the coercion part, using `try:` and `except:`. However, this doesn't answer the testing question.

In the original function:

```py
def cInt(arg):
    tmp = arg
    try:
        arg = int(float(arg))
        if arg == float(tmp):
            return arg
        else:
            return tmp
    except:
        return tmp


def xor(*args, parity = True):
    exOr = False
    checker = list()
    for arg in args:
        arg = cInt(arg)
        exOr ^= arg if type(arg) == int else bool(arg)
        checker.append(bool(arg))
    exOr = 0 if all(checker) and not parity else exOr
    return int(exOr)

xor(1, '1.0', "1")
xor(1, '1.0', "1", parity = False)
```

> 1
> 0

Comment: Turns out it's easy to search for a truth table for 4-bit xor. For example: https://www.mtholyoke.edu/courses/dstrahma/cs221/homework/logicworkshw.htm

Comment: Replit.com has a python environment and a Unit Tests interface that can be setup to test code. I was able to generate tests through 4-bit binary as of this post. However, I'd prefer not to depend on a gui.