# Example of XOR Operator in Python

Tags: python

Can someone give a suitable example of the XOR Operator in Python ? I understand its definition but couldn’t implement it. So, please explain with a suitable example.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The bitwise XOR operator in python is `^`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you get the logical xor of two variables in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432842/how-do-you-get-the-logical-xor-of-two-variables-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fair enough implementation:

```
def xor(a:bool, b:bool)->bool:
    return (not a) == (b)
```

Comment: Wouldn't this return only `True` or `False` ?

Comment: If they're both actually `bool`, you can just test `a != b`.

Comment: @CoolCoder: Which is correct for a boolean xor, just not bitwise xor.

Comment: And if they're not, `bool(a) != bool(b)`