# XOR operator in pandas query

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe ***df_matching*** that I want to get when 2 columns is not matching at certain values using xor operator so

While this code works:

```
df_matching.query('(group == "treatment" and landing_page != "new_page") or  (group != "treatment" and landing_page == "new_page")')
```

This code doesn't:

```
df_matching.query('(group == "treatment") ^ (landing_page == "new_page")')
```

Although all the searches leads that XOR operator in python is "^" and I know that XOR in SQL is XOR but neither works. What is the best way to put XOR in df.query()?

Comment: How about `(group == "treatment") != (landing_page == "new_page")`?

Comment: @Barmar as a concept it is not correct   
look at the following answer in this   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432842/how-do-you-get-the-logical-xor-of-two-variables-in-python  
"There is problem with using "!=" as xor. You would probably expect bool(a) != bool(b) != bool(c) to be the same as bool(a) ^ bool(b) ^ bool(c). So do casts to bool, but I would recommend ^. To know what's going up in the first example look up "operator chaining"

Comment: That's why I didn't post it as an answer.

Comment: @Barmat then it is accepted as a workaround :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't know when they introduced the `^` bitwise XOR but in my current pandas 1.3.5 it's working, although not in `query()` statements. The solution would be:

```py
# create boolean masks A and B
A = df_matching.group == 'treatment'
B = df_matching.landing_page == 'new_page'
df_matching[A ^ B]
```

Answer (score 0):

The python bitwise XOR (`^`) isn't valid in a pandas query, as you noted. It doesn't look like there's a packaged pd.query() XOR function.

To compensate, I'd use the basic definition of a 2-element XOR, i.e, `( A | B ) & ~( A & B )`, and set conditions as variables.

```
a = 'group == "treatment"'
b = 'landing_page == "new_page"'

xor_ab = '('+a+'|'+b+') & ~('+a+'&'+b+')'

df_matching.query(xor_ab)
```

(Slightly more compact.)

Comment: it is more neat and readable but I'm looking for xor operator. or a documented answer that it doesn't have which would be very strange!